# How to convert a std::string to const char* or char*

Tags: c++, string, char, stdstring

How can I convert an `std::string` to a `char*` or a `const char*`?

Comment: Instead of:
char * writable = new char[str.size() + 1];
You can use
char writable[str.size() + 1]; Then you don't need to worry about deleting writable or exception handling.

Comment: You can't use str.size() unless the size is known at compile time, also it might overflow your stack if the fixed size value is huge.

Comment: char* result = strcpy((char*)malloc(str.length()+1), str.c_str());

Comment: @cegprakash `strcpy` and `malloc` aren't really the C++ way.

Comment: @boycy: you mean they are imaginary?

Comment: No, but `char* dest = new char[str.length() + 1]; std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), dest)` would be more idiomatic C++. `strcpy()` and `malloc()` aren't wrong or problematic, but it seems inconsistent to use a C++ string and C library facilities with C++ equivalents in the same block of code.

Comment: `stringName.c_str()` so long as it's a `std::string`, `std::wstring`, or something like a `winrt::hstring`.

Answer (score 1284, accepted):

If you just want to pass a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to a function that needs `const char *`, you can use [`.c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str):

```
std::string str;
const char * c = str.c_str();
```

And if you need a non-const `char *`, call [`.data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data):

```
std::string str;
char * c = str.data();
```

`.data()` was added in C++17. Before that, you can use `&str[0]`.

Note that if the `std::string` is `const`, `.data()` will return `const char *` instead, like `.c_str()`.

The pointer becomes invalid if the string is destroyed or reallocates memory.

The pointer points to a null-terminated string, and the terminator doesn't count against `str.size()`. You're not allowed to assign a non-null character to the terminator.

Comment: Simply use char *result = strdup(str.c_str());

Comment: you could, but strdup is not a c or c++ standard function, it's from posix :)

Comment: what i would probably prefer generally is std::vector<char> writable(str.begin(), str.end()); writable.push_back('\0'); char * c = &writable[0];

Comment: You could also construct the vector with: vector<char> writable(str.c_str(), str.size() + 1);

Comment: Definitely use std::vector. Allocating the array of char is not exception safe.

Comment: I agree: litb, you should add your "vector" solution to your main answer, as it is (exception-) safer than the raw new/delete solution.

Comment: I'm curious why you're bending over backwards to use std::copy().  Wouldn't using strcpy( the_destination, str.c_str()) - or strlcpy() if you have it - work as well and be more immediately obvious what's going on?  strcpy() will work with any of scoped_array, vector, or a raw memory allocation.

Comment: std::copy is the c++ way of doing this, without the need of getting at the string pointer. I try to avoid using C functions as much as i can.

Comment: @efotinis: Which vector constructor is `vector<char> writable(str.c_str(), str.size() + 1);` using?

Comment: @Paul Baker: That's an imaginary ctor I've come up with :)  I've mixed it up with std::string's ctor (or maybe it was a non-standard extension of VC6... *shudder*). Anyway, my preferred solution is the one mentioned in litb's comment above (with begin/end iters).

Comment: BTW, if you use something like strdup(), you must call free() later (as opposed to delete []).

Comment: I'd suggest it is equally the "C++ way" to simply mutate std::string in-place as its public interface exposes `char &operator[]`: this is specified and guaranteed behaviour.

Comment: Is `char *p = const_cast<char*>(str.c_str())` an option (albeit a bad one)?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was young...forgive me. :(

Comment: You should add a comment "DON'T DO THIS" next to the `new char[..]` statement. I suspect that many people just copy/paste the code sample without reading the accompanying text.

Comment: As a C++ neophyte, why wouldn't I just use std::strcpy(dest, str.c_str())?

Comment: @Finster that's totally fine and perhaps I would have used it in real code aswell when in hurry :) I just like to use `std::copy` when I have time to make nice code. Let's not forget there's a difference (albeit an unlikely one with real strings - but who knows what he's going to store). The `std::copy` will copy embedded null bytes aswell, till the end of the `std::string`.

Comment: Why not copy the string and pass &copy[0] for a writable char* of a fixed size?

Comment: char* result = strcpy((char*)malloc(str.length()+1), str.c_str());

Comment: Instead of `std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), writable);
writable[str.size()] = '\0';`, why not just use `std::copy(str.begin(),str.end() + 1,writable);`?

Comment: @rsethc because in C++03 that was not valid. I am not sure what the exact rule in C++11 and C++14 is for it. They guarantee that the string is zero terminated and contiguous, at least

Comment: Ah, so in 03 it was not guaranteed to have a null terminator? That makes sense.

Comment: @rsethc what I worried more about is the `end() + 1`, not so much about the null terminator (I am no library expert, but I don't think that any of the popular library implementations around today have `std::string` without a trailing `\0`). In debug builds, some library implementations have containers where `.end()` returns a class object that throws/core-dumps on `.end() + 1`. So I better be cautious and write code that I definitely know works :)

Comment: That sounds incredibly wasteful, but I'm sure there's some reason for it. I very rarely use the C++ standard library and stick to the C stdlib, so I haven't had much practice with these. Would have expected that `.end()` would return a pointer-size int, or something similar.

Comment: For the first code block, is it deep or shallow copy that is performed?

Comment: Solutions involving `strcpy()` or `strdup()` can fail if the `std::string` contains embedded null characters.

Comment: Instead of `boost::scoped_array<char>`, one can also use `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` from the STL:

`std::unique_ptr<char[]> writable(new char[str.size() + 1]);`. It also deallocates the array using `delete[]` when it goes out of scope.

Comment: As of C++17, [`std::string::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) now returns a `CharT*` instead of a `const CharT*`. It might be a good idea to update this answer :)

Comment: Given that the issues with simply using `data` or `&s[0]` have been fixed for three released language versions now, this all seems overly complicated. Even if the string is `const`, a simple copy of it should be enough.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<char[]> writable(str.size() + 1)` can be used the same way as `boost::scoped_array`

Comment: I've took liberty to remove the mention of manual memory management (we shouldn't recommend that), and other ways of managing memory (if you want a mutable copy of the string, just copy the string).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I can't imagine why you would *remove* it from the answer. The char* copy approach was nearly exactly what I was looking for. Please keep in mind that answers aren't just *recommendations* and that their authors are not simply writing code *for* other people. Answers are for informational purposes. If there is a concern you have with an answer, I would suggest you make note of it in the comments, or better, directly in the answer. Almost 2/3rds of the answer seems to have been deleted in your edit.

Comment: @Kröw Can you explain a bit what your use case is? I can't imagine why one would want to allocate a char array manually, except perhaps to pass it to a C library that takes ownership of it.

Answer (score 226):

Given say...

```
std::string x = "hello";
```

### Getting a `char *` or `const char*` from a `string`

**How to get a character pointer that's valid while `x` remains in scope and isn't modified further**

**C++11** simplifies things; the following all give access to the same internal string buffer:

```
const char* p_c_str = x.c_str();
const char* p_data  = x.data();
char* p_writable_data = x.data(); // for non-const x from C++17 
const char* p_x0    = &x[0];

      char* p_x0_rw = &x[0];  // compiles iff x is not const...
```

All the above pointers will hold the *same value* - the address of the first character in the buffer.  Even an empty string has a "first character in the buffer", because C++11 guarantees to always keep an extra NUL/0 terminator character after the explicitly assigned string content (e.g. `std::string("this\0that", 9)` will have a buffer holding `"this\0that\0"`).

Given any of the above pointers:

```
char c = p[n];   // valid for n <= x.size()
                 // i.e. you can safely read the NUL at p[x.size()]
```

Only for the non-`const` pointer `p_writable_data` and from `&x[0]`:

```
p_writable_data[n] = c;
p_x0_rw[n] = c;  // valid for n <= x.size() - 1
                 // i.e. don't overwrite the implementation maintained NUL
```

Writing a NUL elsewhere in the string does *not* change the `string`'s `size()`; `string`'s are allowed to contain any number of NULs - they are given no special treatment by `std::string` (same in C++03).

In **C++03**, things were considerably more complicated (key differences ***highlighted***):

- `x.data()`

  - returns `const char*` to the string's internal buffer ***which wasn't required by the Standard to conclude with a NUL*** (i.e. might be `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']` followed by uninitialised or garbage values, with accidental accesses thereto having *undefined behaviour*).

    - `x.size()` characters are safe to read, i.e. `x[0]` through `x[x.size() - 1]`
    - for empty strings, you're guaranteed some non-NULL pointer to which 0 can be safely added (hurray!), but you shouldn't dereference that pointer.
- `&x[0]`

  - ***for empty strings this has undefined behaviour*** (21.3.4)

    - e.g. given `f(const char* p, size_t n) { if (n == 0) return; ...whatever... }` you mustn't call `f(&x[0], x.size());` when `x.empty()` - just use `f(x.data(), ...)`.
  - otherwise, as per `x.data()` but:

    - for non-`const` `x` this yields a non-`const` `char*` pointer; you can overwrite string content
- `x.c_str()`

  - returns `const char*` to an ASCIIZ (NUL-terminated) representation of the value (i.e. ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0']).
  - although few if any implementations chose to do so, the C++03 Standard was worded to allow the string implementation the freedom to create a ***distinct NUL-terminated buffer*** *on the fly*, from the potentially non-NUL terminated buffer "exposed" by `x.data()` and `&x[0]`
  - `x.size()` + 1 characters are safe to read.
  - guaranteed safe even for empty strings (['\0']).

### Consequences of accessing outside legal indices

Whichever way you get a pointer, you must not access memory further along from the pointer than the characters guaranteed present in the descriptions above.  Attempts to do so have *undefined behaviour*, with a very real chance of application crashes and garbage results even for reads, and additionally wholesale data, stack corruption and/or security vulnerabilities for writes.

### When do those pointers get invalidated?

If you call some `string` member function that modifies the `string` or reserves further capacity, any pointer values returned beforehand by any of the above methods are *invalidated*.  You can use those methods again to get another pointer.  (The rules are the same as for iterators into `string`s).

See also *How to get a character pointer valid even after `x` leaves scope or is modified further* below....

### So, which is *better* to use?

From C++11, use `.c_str()` for ASCIIZ data, and `.data()` for "binary" data (explained further below).

In C++03, use `.c_str()` unless certain that `.data()` is adequate, and prefer `.data()` over `&x[0]` as it's safe for empty strings....

*...try to understand the program enough to use `data()` when appropriate, or you'll probably make other mistakes...*

The ASCII NUL '\0' character guaranteed by `.c_str()` is used by many functions as a sentinel value denoting the end of relevant and safe-to-access data.  This applies to both C++-only functions like say `fstream::fstream(const char* filename, ...)` and shared-with-C functions like `strchr()`, and `printf()`.

Given C++03's `.c_str()`'s guarantees about the returned buffer are a super-set of `.data()`'s, you can always safely use `.c_str()`, but people sometimes don't because:

- using `.data()` communicates to other programmers reading the source code that the data is not ASCIIZ (rather, you're using the string to store a block of data (which sometimes isn't even really textual)), or that you're passing it to another function that treats it as a block of "binary" data.  This can be a crucial insight in ensuring that other programmers' code changes continue to handle the data properly.
- C++03 only: there's a slight chance that your `string` implementation will need to do some extra memory allocation and/or data copying in order to prepare the NUL terminated buffer

As a further hint, if a function's parameters require the (`const`) `char*` but don't insist on getting `x.size()`, the function *probably* needs an ASCIIZ input, so `.c_str()` is a good choice (the function needs to know where the text terminates somehow, so if it's not a separate parameter it can only be a convention like a length-prefix or sentinel or some fixed expected length).

### How to get a character pointer valid even after `x` leaves scope or is modified further

You'll need to ***copy*** the contents of the `string` `x` to a new memory area outside `x`.  This external buffer could be in many places such as another `string` or character array variable, it may or may not have a different lifetime than `x` due to being in a different scope (e.g. namespace, global, static, heap, shared memory, memory mapped file).

To copy the text from `std::string x` into an independent character array:

```
// USING ANOTHER STRING - AUTO MEMORY MANAGEMENT, EXCEPTION SAFE
std::string old_x = x;
// - old_x will not be affected by subsequent modifications to x...
// - you can use `&old_x[0]` to get a writable char* to old_x's textual content
// - you can use resize() to reduce/expand the string
//   - resizing isn't possible from within a function passed only the char* address

std::string old_x = x.c_str(); // old_x will terminate early if x embeds NUL
// Copies ASCIIZ data but could be less efficient as it needs to scan memory to
// find the NUL terminator indicating string length before allocating that amount
// of memory to copy into, or more efficient if it ends up allocating/copying a
// lot less content.
// Example, x == "ab\0cd" -> old_x == "ab".

// USING A VECTOR OF CHAR - AUTO, EXCEPTION SAFE, HINTS AT BINARY CONTENT, GUARANTEED CONTIGUOUS EVEN IN C++03
std::vector<char> old_x(x.data(), x.data() + x.size());       // without the NUL
std::vector<char> old_x(x.c_str(), x.c_str() + x.size() + 1);  // with the NUL

// USING STACK WHERE MAXIMUM SIZE OF x IS KNOWN TO BE COMPILE-TIME CONSTANT "N"
// (a bit dangerous, as "known" things are sometimes wrong and often become wrong)
char y[N + 1];
strcpy(y, x.c_str());

// USING STACK WHERE UNEXPECTEDLY LONG x IS TRUNCATED (e.g. Hello\0->Hel\0)
char y[N + 1];
strncpy(y, x.c_str(), N);  // copy at most N, zero-padding if shorter
y[N] = '\0';               // ensure NUL terminated

// USING THE STACK TO HANDLE x OF UNKNOWN (BUT SANE) LENGTH
char* y = alloca(x.size() + 1);
strcpy(y, x.c_str());

// USING THE STACK TO HANDLE x OF UNKNOWN LENGTH (NON-STANDARD GCC EXTENSION)
char y[x.size() + 1];
strcpy(y, x.c_str());

// USING new/delete HEAP MEMORY, MANUAL DEALLOC, NO INHERENT EXCEPTION SAFETY
char* y = new char[x.size() + 1];
strcpy(y, x.c_str());
//     or as a one-liner: char* y = strcpy(new char[x.size() + 1], x.c_str());
// use y...
delete[] y; // make sure no break, return, throw or branching bypasses this

// USING new/delete HEAP MEMORY, SMART POINTER DEALLOCATION, EXCEPTION SAFE
// see boost shared_array usage in Johannes Schaub's answer

// USING malloc/free HEAP MEMORY, MANUAL DEALLOC, NO INHERENT EXCEPTION SAFETY
char* y = strdup(x.c_str());
// use y...
free(y);
```

### Other reasons to want a `char*` or `const char*` generated from a `string`

So, above you've seen how to get a (`const`) `char*`, and how to make a copy of the text independent of the original `string`, but what can you *do* with it?  A random smattering of examples...

- give "C" code access to the C++ `string`'s text, as in `printf("x is '%s'", x.c_str());`
- copy `x`'s text to a buffer specified by your function's caller (e.g. `strncpy(callers_buffer, callers_buffer_size, x.c_str())`), or volatile memory used for device I/O (e.g. `for (const char* p = x.c_str(); *p; ++p) *p_device = *p;`)
- append `x`'s text to an character array already containing some ASCIIZ text (e.g. `strcat(other_buffer, x.c_str())`) - be careful not to overrun the buffer (in many situations you may need to use `strncat`)
- return a `const char*` or `char*` from a function (perhaps for historical reasons - client's using your existing API - or for C compatibility you don't want to return a `std::string`, but do want to copy your `string`'s data somewhere for the caller)

  - be careful not to return a pointer that may be dereferenced by the caller after a local `string` variable to which that pointer pointed has left scope
  - some projects with shared objects compiled/linked for different `std::string` implementations (e.g. STLport and compiler-native) may pass data as ASCIIZ to avoid conflicts

Comment: Nice one. Another reason to want a char* (non const) is to operate with MPI broadcast. It looks nicer if you don't have to copy back and forth. I would have personally offered a char* const getter to string. Const pointer, but editable string. Although it may have messed with the implicit conversion from const char* to string...

Answer (score 39):

Use the `.c_str()` method for `const char *`.

You can use `&mystring[0]` to get a `char *` pointer, but there are a couple of gotcha's: you won't necessarily get a zero terminated string, and you won't be able to change the string's size. You especially have to be careful not to add characters past the end of the string or you'll get a buffer overrun (and probable crash).

There was no guarantee that all of the characters would be part of the same contiguous buffer until C++11, but in practice all known implementations of `std::string` worked that way anyway; see [Does “&s[0]” point to contiguous characters in a std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986966/does-s0-point-to-contiguous-characters-in-a-stdstring).

Note that many `string` member functions will reallocate the internal buffer and invalidate any pointers you might have saved. Best to use them immediately and then discard.

Comment: you should note that data() returns const char * :) what you mean is &str[0], which returns a contiguous, but not necassary null terminated string.

Comment: @litb, Argh! That's what I get for trying to whip up a quick answer. I've used your solution in the past, don't know why it wasn't the first thing that came to mind. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Technically, std::string storage will be contiguous only in C++0x.

Comment: @MSalters, thanks - I didn't know that. I'd be hard pressed to find an implementation where that wasn't the case, though.

Comment: char* result = strcpy(malloc(str.length()+1), str.c_str());

Answer (score 24):

### C++17

**C++17** (upcoming standard) changes the synopsis of the template `basic_string` adding a non const overload of `data()`:

> `charT* data() noexcept;`
>
> Returns: A pointer p such that p + i == &operator for each i in [0,size()].

---

#### `CharT const *` from `std::basic_string<CharT>`

```
std::string const cstr = { "..." };
char const * p = cstr.data(); // or .c_str()
```

#### `CharT *` from `std::basic_string<CharT>`

```
std::string str = { "..." };
char * p = str.data();
```

### C++11

## `CharT const *` from `std::basic_string<CharT>`

```
std::string str = { "..." };
str.c_str();
```

## `CharT *` from `std::basic_string<CharT>`

From C++11 onwards, the standard says:

> 1. The char-like objects in a `basic_string` object shall be stored contiguously. That is, for any `basic_string` object `s`, the identity `&*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n` shall hold for all values of `n` such that `0 <= n < s.size()`.
>
> ---
>
> 2. `const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;` 
>     `reference operator[](size_type pos);`
>
>    Returns: `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`, otherwise a reference to an object of type `CharT` with value `CharT()`; the referenced value shall not be modified.
>
> ---
>
> 3. `const charT* c_str() const noexcept;`
>    `const charT* data() const noexcept;`
>
>    Returns: A pointer p such that `p + i == &operator[](i)` for each `i` in `[0,size()]`.

There are severable possible ways to get a non const character pointer.

#### 1. Use the contiguous storage of C++11

```
std::string foo{"text"};
auto p = &*foo.begin();
```

**Pro**

- Simple and short
- Fast (only method with no copy involved)

**Cons**

- Final `'\0'` is not to be altered / not necessarily part of the non-const memory.

#### 2. Use `std::vector<CharT>`

```
std::string foo{"text"};
std::vector<char> fcv(foo.data(), foo.data()+foo.size()+1u);
auto p = fcv.data();
```

**Pro**

- Simple
- Automatic memory handling
- Dynamic

**Cons**

- Requires string copy

#### 3. Use `std::array<CharT, N>` if `N` is compile time constant (and small enough)

```
std::string foo{"text"};
std::array<char, 5u> fca;
std::copy(foo.data(), foo.data()+foo.size()+1u, fca.begin());
```

**Pro**

- Simple
- Stack memory handling

**Cons**

- Static
- Requires string copy

#### 4. Raw memory allocation with automatic storage deletion

```
std::string foo{ "text" };
auto p = std::make_unique<char[]>(foo.size()+1u);
std::copy(foo.data(), foo.data() + foo.size() + 1u, &p[0]);
```

**Pro**

- Small memory footprint
- Automatic deletion
- Simple

**Cons**

- Requires string copy
- Static (dynamic usage requires lots more code)
- Less features than vector or array

#### 5. Raw memory allocation with manual handling

```
std::string foo{ "text" };
char * p = nullptr;
try
{
  p = new char[foo.size() + 1u];
  std::copy(foo.data(), foo.data() + foo.size() + 1u, p);
  // handle stuff with p
  delete[] p;
}
catch (...)
{
  if (p) { delete[] p; }
  throw;
}
```

**Pro**

- Maximum 'control'

**Con**

- Requires string copy
- Maximum liability / susceptibility for errors
- Complex

Answer (score 10):

I am working with an API with a lot of functions that get a `char*` as an input.

I have created a small class to face this kind of problem, and I have implemented the [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom.

```
class DeepString
{
        DeepString(const DeepString& other);
        DeepString& operator=(const DeepString& other);
        char* internal_; 
    
    public:
        explicit DeepString( const string& toCopy): 
            internal_(new char[toCopy.size()+1]) 
        {
            strcpy(internal_,toCopy.c_str());
        }
        ~DeepString() { delete[] internal_; }
        char* str() const { return internal_; }
        const char* c_str()  const { return internal_; }
};
```

And you can use it as:

```
void aFunctionAPI(char* input);

//  other stuff

aFunctionAPI("Foo"); //this call is not safe. if the function modified the 
                     //literal string the program will crash
std::string myFoo("Foo");
aFunctionAPI(myFoo.c_str()); //this is not compiling
aFunctionAPI(const_cast<char*>(myFoo.c_str())); //this is not safe std::string 
                                                //implement reference counting and 
                                                //it may change the value of other
                                                //strings as well.
DeepString myDeepFoo(myFoo);
aFunctionAPI(myFoo.str()); //this is fine
```

I have called the class `DeepString` because it is creating a deep and unique copy (the `DeepString` is not copyable) of an existing string.

Comment: I would avoid this naming convention. `c_str()` as used by `std` is an abbreviation for "C-string" not "const string" and `str()` always returns a `std::basic_string`, not `char*` (for example `std::stringstream::str()`)

Answer (score 10):

Just see this:

```
string str1("stackoverflow");
const char * str2 = str1.c_str();
```

However, note that this will return a `const char *`.

For a `char *`, use `strcpy` to copy it into another `char` array.

Comment: Hi, what you posted has already been said multiple times, with more details, in other answers to the 5 year old question. It's fine to answer older questions, but only if you add new information. Otherwise, it's just noise.

Comment: Personally, I appreciate the simplicity.

Answer (score 9):

```
char* result = strcpy((char*)malloc(str.length()+1), str.c_str());
```

Comment: looks fancy but really hard to understand... Simple is the best IMO

Comment: strcpy(), malloc(), length() and c_str() are basic functions and there is nothing hard in this. Just allocating memory and copying.

Comment: yes the functions are basic but you've twisted and bent them to look like bowl of spaghetti or one liner Frankenstein's monster :)

Comment: __Yes the functions are basic but...__ did you remember when you start to deal with a programming language? Some lines more to explain and it will really help a neophyte to learn why for example is different or better than [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16505452/3569208):)

Comment: @cegprakash: Whenever there is a malloc(), there also has to be a free(). Otherwise the code leaks memory, and so does the solution in your answer. Allocating memory without at least hinting to the required deallocation is bad practice for such questions.

Answer (score 2):

**Converting from c++ std string to C style string is really easy now.**

For that we have `string::copy` function which will easily convert std string to C style string. [reference](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/copy/)

`string::copy` functions parameters serially

1. char string pointer
2. string size, how many characters will b copied
3. position, from where character copy will start

Another important thing,

This function does not append a null character at the end of operation. So, we need to put it manually.

Code exam are in below -

```
// char string
char chText[20];

// c++ string
string text =  "I am a Programmer";

// conversion from c++ string to char string
// this function does not append a null character at the end of operation
text.copy(chText, text.size(), 0);

// we need to put it manually
chText[text.size()] = '\0';

// below statement prints "I am a Programmer"
cout << chText << endl;
```

Vice Versa, **Converting from C style string to C++ std string is lot more easier**

There is three ways we can convert from C style string to C++ std string

First one is using constructor,

```
char chText[20] = "I am a Programmer";
// using constructor
string text(chText);
```

Second one is using `string::assign` method

```
// char string
char chText[20] = "I am a Programmer";

// c++ string
string text;

// convertion from char string to c++ string
// using assign function
text.assign(chText);
```

Third one is assignment operator(=), in which string class uses operator overloading

```
// char string
char chText[20] = "I am a Programmer";

// c++ string
// convertion from char string to c++ string using assignment operator overloading
string text = chText;
```

third one can be also write like below -

```
// char string
char chText[20] = "I am a Programmer";

// c++ string
string text;


// convertion from char string to c++ string
text = chText;
```

Answer (score 0):

let's say,
string str="stack";

1)**converting string to char***

```
  char* s_rw=&str[0];
```

The above char*(i.e., s_rw) is readable and writeable and points to the base
address of the string which needs to be converted to char*

2)**Converting string to const char***

```
   const char* s_r=&str[0];
```

The above const char* (i.e., s_r) is readable but not writeable and points to the
base address of the string.

Answer (score -1):

This is especially useful when passing the underlying `char*` buffer of a `std::string` to C calls which expect and write to a `char*` buffer. This way you get the best of both worlds!: the niceties of the C++ `std::string` and the usability of it directly with C libraries you are calling from C++.

### How to use a *modern* C++ `std::string` as a C-style read/writable `char*` or read-only null-terminated `const char*`

> How can I convert a `std::string` to a `char*` or a `const char*`?

Despite being a really old and highly-upvoted question, the information I'm about to cover isn't already well-covered, if covered at all, so this is a necessary addition, *in particular* the part about needing to pre-allocate the underlying C-string using the `.resize()` method if you'd like to use it as a writable buffer.

All of the usages below require **C++11** or later, except for the [`char* data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) call, which requires **C++17** or later.

To run and test all example code below, and more, see and run my [string__use_std_string_as_a_c_str_buffer.cpp](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/cpp/string__use_std_string_as_a_c_str_buffer.cpp) file in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo.

### Quick summary:

```cpp
#include <string>
constexpr size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 100;
std::string str;
// IMPORTANT: pre-allocate the underlying buffer to guarantee what size it is
str.resize(BUFFER_SIZE); 

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Get read-writeable access to the underlying `char*` C-string at index i
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

char* c_str1 = &str[i]; // <=== my favorite!
char* c_str2 = str.data() + i;
char* c_str3 = &(*str.begin()) + i;

// NB: the C-strings above are NOT guaranteed to be null-terminated, so manually
// write in a null terminator at the index location where you want it if
// desired. Ex:
//
// 1. write a null terminator at some arbitrary position you choose (index 10
// here)
c_str1[10] = '\0'; 
// 2. write a null terminator at the last guaranteed valid position in the 
// underlying C-string/array of chars
c_str2[str.size() - i - 1] = '\0';

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Get read-only access to the underlying `const char*` C-string at index i
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
const char* const_c_str1 = &str[i];
const char* const_c_str2 = str.c_str() + i; // guaranteed to be null-terminated,
                                            // but not necessarily at the
                                            // position you desire; the
                                            // guaranteed null terminator will
                                            // be at index location 
                                            // `str.size()`
```

### Summary:

If in a hurry and you need:

1. A read-writable `char*` C-string of the underlying buffer: just use section A Technique 1 in the code example just below: `char* c_str1 = &str[i];`.

   1. Just be sure to pre-allocate the underlying buffer size *first* via `str.resize(BUFFER_SIZE)`, if needed, is all, to ensure the underlying buffer is big enough for your needs.
2. A read-only `const char*` C-string of the underlying buffer: use the same thing as above (`const char* const_c_str1 = &str[i];`), *or* `const char* const_c_str1 = str.c_str() + i;`.

```cpp
#include <string>

constexpr size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 100;

std::string str;
// IMPORTANT: pre-allocate the underlying buffer to guarantee what size it is
str.resize(BUFFER_SIZE);  

// =============================================================================
// Now you can use the `std::string`'s underlying buffer directly as a C-string
// =============================================================================

// ---------------------------------------------------------
// A. As a read-writeable `char*` C-string
// ---------------------------------------------------------

// Technique 1 [best option if using C++11]: array indexing using `operator[]` 
// to obtain a char, followed by obtaining its address with `&`
// - Documentation: 
//   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at
char* c_str1 = &str[0];
char* c_str2 = &str[10];
char* c_str3 = &str[33];
// etc. 

// Technique 2 [best option if using C++17]: use the `.data()` method to obtain
// a `char*` directly.
// - Documentation: 
//   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data
char* c_str11 = str.data();      // same as c_str1 above
char* c_str12 = str.data() + 10; // same as c_str2 above
char* c_str13 = str.data() + 33; // same as c_str3 above

// Technique 3 [fine in C++11 or later, but is awkward, so don't do this. It is
// for demonstration and learning purposes only]: use the `.begin()` method to
// obtain an iterator to the first char, and then use the iterator's 
// `operator*()` dereference method to obtain the iterator's `char`
// `value_type`, and then take the address of that to obtain a `char*`
// - Documentation:
//   - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/begin
//   - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator
char* c_str21 = &(*str.begin());      // same as c_str1 and c_str11 above
char* c_str22 = &(*str.begin()) + 10; // same as c_str2 and c_str12 above
char* c_str23 = &(*str.begin()) + 33; // same as c_str3 and c_str13 above


// ---------------------------------------------------------
// B. As a read-only, null-terminated `const char*` C-string
// ---------------------------------------------------------

// - Documentation:
//   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str

const char* const_c_str1 = str.c_str();      // a const version of c_str1 above
const char* const_c_str2 = str.c_str() + 10; // a const version of c_str2 above
const char* const_c_str3 = str.c_str() + 33; // a const version of c_str3 above
```

Note that you can also use the `.at(i)` and `.front()` `std::string` methods too, but I won't go into those since I think my examples are sufficient. For their documentation, see:

1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at
2. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/front

### Details:

See also the note just above. I'm not going to cover the techniques using the `.at(i)` and `.front()` `std::string` methods, since I think the several techniques I already present are sufficient.

### 1. Use a `std::string` as a read/writable `char*`

To use a C++ `std::string` as a C-style *writable* `char*` buffer, you MUST first pre-allocate the string's internal buffer to change its `.size()` by using `.resize()`. Note that using `.reserve()` to increase only the `.capacity()` is NOT sufficient! The [cppreference.com community wiki page for `std::string::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) correctly states:

> If `pos > size()`, the behavior is undefined.

The `resize()` method is what changes the size, *not* the `reserve()` method, which changes only the `capacity()`.

Ex:

```cpp
#include <cstring>  // `strcpy()`
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


constexpr size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 100;

std::string str;
str.resize(BUFFER_SIZE);  // pre-allocate the underlying buffer
// check the size
std::cout << "str.size() = " << str.size() << "\n";
```

**For all examples below, assume you have these C-strings:**

```cpp
constexpr char cstr1[] = "abcde ";
constexpr char cstr2[] = "fghijk";
```

Once you have pre-allocated an underlying buffer which is sufficiently large with `resize()`, you can then access the underlying buffer as
a `char*` in at least 3 ways:

1. **Technique 1 [best option if using C++11]: array indexing using `operator[]` to obtain a char, followed by obtaining its address with `&`.** Ex:

   ```cpp
   char* c_str;
   c_str = &str[0];
   c_str = &str[5]; 
   // etc.

   // Write these 2 C-strings into a `std::string`'s underlying buffer
   strcpy(&str[0], cstr1);
   strcpy(&str[sizeof(cstr1) - 1], cstr2); // `- 1` to overwrite the first 
                                           // null terminator

   // print the string
   std::cout << str << "\n"; // output: `abcde fghijk`
   ```

   What if you have a pointer to a `std::string`? If you have a ptr to a `std::string`, it must be dereferenced first with `*pstr` before you can index into it as an array with the `operator[]` as `&(*pstr)[0]`, so the syntax above becomes a little more awkward. Here is a full example:

   ```cpp
   std::string str2;
   std::string* pstr = &str2;
   pstr->resize(BUFFER_SIZE);
   c_str = &(*pstr)[0]; // <=== dereference the ptr 1st before indexing into it
   // Or, to make the order of precedence 
   // (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) really
   // obvious, you can optionally add extra parenthesis like this:
   c_str = &((*pstr)[0]);
   ```
2. **Technique 2 [best option if using C++17]: use the `.data()` method to obtain a `char*` directly.** Ex:

   ```cpp
   char* c_str;
   c_str = str.data();
   c_str = str.data() + 5;
   // etc.

   // Write these 2 C-strings into the `std::string`'s underlying buffer
   strcpy(str.data(), cstr1);
   strcpy(str.data() + (sizeof(cstr1) - 1), cstr2); // `- 1` to overwrite the
                                                    // first null terminator

   // print the string
   std::cout << str << "\n"; // output: `abcde fghijk`
   ```
3. **Technique 3 [fine in C++11 and later, but is awkward, so don't do this. It is for demonstration and learning purposes only]: use the `.begin()` method to obtain an iterator to the first char, and then use the iterator's `operator*()` dereference method to obtain the iterator's `char` `value_type`, and then take the address of that to obtain a `char*`.** Ex:

   ```cpp
   char* c_str;
   c_str = &(*str.begin());
   c_str = &(*str.begin()) + 5;
   // etc.

   // Write these 2 C-strings into the `std::string`'s underlying buffer
   strcpy(&(*str.begin()), cstr1);
   strcpy(&(*str.begin()) + (sizeof(cstr1) - 1), cstr2); // `- 1` to overwrite 
                                                         // the first null 
                                                         // terminator

   // print the string
   std::cout << str << "\n"; // output: `abcde fghijk`
   ```

Something important to be aware of is that when you call `str.resize(100)`, it reserves at least 100 bytes for the underlying string, sets the `size()` of the string to `100`, and initializes all `100` of those chars to `char()`--AKA: the default *value initialization* value for `char` ([see my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72367123/4561887)), which is the binary zero null-terminator, `'\0'`. Therefore, whenever you call `str.size()` it will return `100` even if the string simply has `"hello"` in it followed by 95 null-terminators, or zeros. To get the *length*, or number of *non-null-terminators* in the string, you'll have to resort to the C function `strlen()`, like this:

```cpp
std::cout << strlen(str.c_str()) << "\n"; // prints `12` in the examples above

// instead of:
std::cout << str.size() << "\n"; // prints `100` in the examples above
```

### 2. Access a `std::string` as a read-only, null-terminated `const char*`

To obtain a *readable* null-terminated `const char*` from a `std::string`, use the [`.c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method. It returns a C-style string that is *guaranteed to be null-terminated*. Note that the [`.data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) method is NOT the same thing, as it is NOT guaranteed to be null-terminated!

Example:

```cpp
std::string str = "hello world";
printf("%s\n", str.c_str());
```

### References

1. (questions on Stack Overflow)

   1. How to convert a std::string to const char* or char*:
      [How to convert a std::string to const char* or char*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/347949/4561887)
   2. Directly write into char* buffer of std::string:
      [Directly write into char* buffer of std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39200665/4561887)
   3. Is there a way to get std:string's buffer:
      [Is there a way to get std:string's buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7836863/4561887)
2. (my content)

   1. [my test code] [string__use_std_string_as_a_c_str_buffer.cpp](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/cpp/string__use_std_string_as_a_c_str_buffer.cpp)
   2. [my Q] See the "Adjacently related" section at the bottom of my question here:
      [What is a call to `char()`, `uint8_t()`, `int64_t()`, integer `T()`, etc, as a function in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72367123/4561887)
   3. *****+ [my comments about pre-allocating a buffer in the std::string]:
      [Directly write into char* buffer of std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39200665/directly-write-into-char-buffer-of-stdstring#comment127844941_39200666)
   4. *****+ [my comment on how to pre-allocate storage in a std::string, to be used as a char* buffer]
      [Is there a way to get std:string's buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836863/is-there-a-way-to-get-stdstrings-buffer#comment127847227_15863513)
3. (from the cppreference.com community wiki)

   1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string:

      > The elements of a basic_string are stored contiguously, that is, for a basic_string s, &*(s.begin
      > () + n) == &*s.begin() + n for any n in [0, s.size()), or, equivalently, a pointer to s[0] can
      > be passed to functions that expect a pointer to the first element of a null-terminated
      > (since C++11)CharT[] array.
   2. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at

      > Returns a reference to the character at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed.
      > If pos > size(), the behavior is undefined.
   3. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize
   4. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve
   5. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data
   6. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str
   7. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
std::string s(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(Data), Size);
```