# STL map and c++

Tags: c++, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert std::string to const char* or char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

is there any to get the string back from the stl map and into a char array??

```
multimap<string, string> testcase;
testcase.insert(pair<string,string>("DB","something"));
for( i=testcase.begin(); i!=testcase.end(); ++i){
            char cate[20] =(*i).first;
```

my code looks something like this... hw can i save (*i).first(or second for that matter) into a character array?

Comment: Duplicate of [Convert std::string to const char* or char*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char) (this has nothing to do with `std::map` at all.

Comment: Yes there is a way (or there are ways), as per James' comment, but *why* do you want to populate the char-array? What's the real problem that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know the size of the string, using what appears to be your original intention:

```
char cate[20];
assert(i->first.size() < sizeof(cate));
strcpy(i->first.c_str());
```

However if you want to take a copy of the string you want:

```
string cate(i->first);
```

Or C-style:

```
char *cate(strdup(i->first.c_str()));
```

Lastly to access the string with a "C" pointer:

```
char const *cate = i->first.c_str();
```

Answer (score 0):

all i had to do was this.. strcpy never hit me. Thanks matt.

```
char cate[20];
char server[30];
strcpy(cate,i->first.c_str());
strcpy(server,i->first.c_str());
```