# How to convert a C++ string to a char*?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert std::string to const char* or char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

Simple question but I'm new to C++. How do I convert a string to a `char *` (I read a string from `cin` then I have a function that operates on `char[]` so need to get a `char *`)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/).

Comment: Note that c_str() gives a 'const char *', not a 'char *'. May not be useful, and could be dangerous if used incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

See [How to convert a std::string to const char* or char*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char).

Comment: And whoever can vote this question duplicated - please do...