# Converting std string to const char*

Tags: c++, file-io

I am getting an error when I run this piece of code

```
  string line;
  getline (myfile,line);
  char file_input[15];
  strncpy(file_input, line, 6);
  cout << line << endl;
```

Error - cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)’
How to get rid of this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? While you can get rid of this error rather easily, there’s probably a better alternative than using a fixed-sized buffer to begin with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert std::string to const char* or char*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strncpy(file_input, line.c_str(), 6);
```

But why would you want the fixed-length buffer `file_input` in the first place? It would be safer to construct it as a new `std::string` containing the first five characters in `line`:

```
std::string file_input(line, 0, 5);
```

Comment: I want to perform some operations like substring, string comparison etc with the string input taken from file.

Comment: @Vishal: then use `std::string`, which has all these operations and makes them a lot easier. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: If you're going to use a lot of `substring`, I suggest using `std::string_view` instead, as it will not build copies, so it will be really good for performance.

Answer (score 5):

Try :

```
strncpy(file_input, line.c_str(), 6);
```

This uses the [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) member function of the `std::string` type.

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS! This is undefined behavior. The prototype for basic_string::c_str() is `const charT* c_str() const;`. The standard goes on to say " The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the array. Nor shall the program treat the returned value as a valid pointer value after any subsequent call to a non-const member function of the class basic_string that designates the same object as `this`."

Comment: @David: Sander is copying *from* `line.c_str()`, not into it. `strncpy`'s argument order reflects the assignment operator's.

Comment: Ignore my the previous comment. I read it exactly backwards. This is a perfectly valid use of c_str().

Answer (score 0):

Converting from c++ std string to C style string is really easy now.

For that we have `string::copy` function which will easily convert std string to C style string. [reference](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/copy/)

`string::copy` functions parameters serially

1. char string pointer
2. string size, how many characters will b copied
3. position, from where character copy will start

Another important thing,

This function does not append a null character at the end of operation. So, we need to put it manually.

Code exam are in below -

```
// char string
char chText[20];

// c++ string
string text =  "I am a Programmer";

// conversion from c++ string to char string
// this function does not append a null character at the end of operation
text.copy(chText, text.size(), 0);

// we need to put it manually
chText[text.size()] = '\0';

// below statement prints "I am a Programmer"
cout << chText << endl;
```