# error C2664: 'callToPrint' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::wstring' to 'LPTSTR'

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I converted a narrow string to the wide string as follows :

```
string nameOfPrinter;
getline( cin , nameOfPrinter );
wstring WprinterName;
int number = MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8 , 0 , nameOfPrinter.c_str() , nameOfPrinter.size() , &WprinterName , 0 );

// then i make a call to the function whose prototype is callToPrint( LPTSTR , LPVOID , DWORD , string )

// the calling statement is :
callToPrint( WprinterName , -----all other arguments-----,);

// But this call produces the following error error C2664: 'callToPrint' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::wstring' to 'LPTSTR'
```

Why is it so ? and please tell me how can i fix it ?

Comment: Probably you should say `WprinterName.c_str()` in your first argument.

Comment: Are you building for unicode? If not, LPTSTR is char *, not wchar_t*

Comment: @ Jeff Paquette writing for unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to use .c_str() here.

Also, I'd read the printer name directly into WprinterName, using

```
getline(wcin, Wprintername);
```

Comment: the line of error after using `WprinterName.c_str` says **error C2664: 'callToPrint' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const wchar_t *'to 'LPTSTR'**

Comment: Can you fix your `callToPrint` function to accept constant strings?

Comment: And in that case, can you fix your `callToPrint` to accept a `std::wstring`?  :-)

Comment: @ Kerrek SB no..In tried casting `wchar*_t` to `LPTSTR` and it worked..How does that work ?

Comment: @ Bo Persson what is the difference between `LPTSTR` and `wstring` ? If the first one is a pointer to wide string and the latter is a wide string then NO

Comment: @Suhail - There are different kinds of strings, C style zero terminated arrays of characters, and C++ classes. `LPTSTR` is a macro that means either `wchar_t*` or `char*` depending on your project settings. With the right setting the cast works (because it doesn't do anything), with the other setting it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `callToPrint` basically states it expects a C string it can modify, i.e. not `const`. Hence the use if `LPTSTR` instead of `LPTCSTR` VC macro. Whether it in fact changes the buffer or not depends on its implementation. Now, `w_string.c_str()` returns a `const wchar_t*`, which according to the definition of [c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) you must not change (even if you can cast it to a `wchar_t*`, in which case your code will compile.

Since `callToPrint` is declared that way, you must provide it with a non-const C string. For that, you can drop the use of `wstring WprinterName`, and use a raw array of wchar_t (or TCHAR, if you want to stick to VC types). Use that buffer in `MultiByteToWideChar` and `callToPrint`, and don't forget to free it at the end...

If you do need the `wstring` for further processing, read: [Convert std::string to const char* or char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char) for some additional suggestions.