# How to convert a string to char[]

Tags: c++, string, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert std::string to const char* or char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

i've got a line from a txt data with this methode

```
 for ( int anrede=0;!user1.eof();anrede++){
     if (anrede==1){
         getline(user1, inhalt_anrede);       
     }
 }
```

now `inhalt_anrede` should be converted to `char[5] anrede` i have used `anrede` in other parts of the program.

so the txt data works like a save-data.

i'm still learning so please be tender ;D.

btw.:  no, this is no homework like someone says about a other question from me. i from germany and in germany there is no C++ @ schools. not even java or delphi. if ur lucky u learn HTML, thats it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::string str("abc");
char cstr[5];
strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());
```

Be sure not to overflow the c string (can contain only 4 chars + NULL in this example).

Comment: Better use strncpy() if str can be longer than 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the c_str() method of the string. For more information look here http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Answer (score 0):

Strings have a c_str() method that returns a `char*`.  If you need it to be a char[5], then copy the first five characters from the string to one.

```
 char strArr[5];
 for (int i = 0; i < 5 && i < inhalt_anrede.length(); ++i) {
     strArr[i] = inhalt_anrede[i];
 }
```

Keep in mind that strArr isn't necessarily `'\0'` terminated now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `c_str()` member of `std::string` and `memcpy`:

```
char anrede[5];
if (anrede.size() >= 5)
    memcpy(anrede, inhalt_anrede.c_str(), 5);
else
    throw "string is too short";
```

Note that you use a variable called `anrede` already as counter in your `for` loop!