# Disappearing contents of std::vector<std::string>

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdvector, stringstream, stdstring

I have a vector of strings which are changing its contents for no apparent reason. Can't really explain what is going on. Sorry for a long listing, but it's really bugging me.

I have a GUI application which loads some files and uses a reader object which state can be set by using a `parse(int argc, char* argv[])` method. The arguments are set in a dialog by checking various boxes and entering values. Here is a struct I use to hold the data from the dialog:

```
struct PointFilter
{
    PointFilter(): argc(0) {};
    ~PointFilter() {};
    int argc;
    std::vector<std::string> args;
};
```

This struct is a member of the dialog class and after pressing ok button its populated with appropriate values. The values are taken from text boxes on the dialog into a stringstream and then pushed back into a std::vector:

```
class AdvancedLoadDialog
{
public:
    AdvancedLoadDialog(const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>&);
    ~AdvancedLoadDialog();

    PointFilter get_point_filter()
    {
        return this->point_filter;
    }

private:
    PointFilter point_filter;
    void on_ok_btn_clicked();

void AdvancedLoadDialog::on_ok_btn_clicked()
{
    std::stringstream filter_stream;
        // filter_stream << some_values_from_textboxes ...

    std::vector<std::string> args;
    std::string arg;

    // we need a dummy first argument to emulate the command line
    args.push_back("filter");

    while (filter_stream >> arg)
    {
        args.push_back(arg);
    }       

    point_filter.argc = args.size() > 1 ? args.size() : 0;
    point_filter.args = args;

    advanced_load_dialog->hide_all();
}
```

Everything works fine till this point and we have an `AdvancedLoadDialog` object with `point_filter` member which holds our arguments. Now in a separate window I take the point_filter object and pass it to a constructor of `LoadWorker` class, which loads the files and also has a `PointFilter` member.

```
load_worker = new LoadWorker(..., advanced_load_dialog->get_point_filter())
```

And then:

```
LoadWorker::LoadWorker(..., PointFilter pf) :
    point_filter    (pf)
```

All well and good. Now in the `LoadWorker::run()` function I take the arguments from the point_filter, convert them into std::vector and pass them them to the `parse(int argc, char* argv[]) function I need.

```
void LoadWorker::run()
{
    std::cout << "LoadWorker::file_filter contents: \n"
            << "point_filter.argc: " << point_filter.argc << "\n"
            << "point_filter.args: " << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < point_filter.argc; ++i)
        std::cout << point_filter.args[i] << std::endl;

        // ...

    if (point_filter.argc != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Using filter: " << std::endl;

        std::vector<char*> argv;

        for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = point_filter.args.begin();
                it != point_filter.args.end(); ++it)
        {
            argv.push_back(const_cast<char*>(it->c_str()));
        }
        argv.push_back(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < point_filter.argc; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
        }

        if (!lasreadopener.parse(point_filter.argc, &argv[0]))
        {
            send_message("Error parsing filter parameters.");
            sig_fail();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Now this works... once. You can notice that the arguments are printed twice, first as elements of `LoadWorker::point_filter.args` vector and then as elements of the `vector<char*> argv`. If I set the filter and then press the load button it all works. If I then try to load another file, without changing `AdvancedLoadDialog::point_filter` at all, the arguments are disappearing. Here's an example output trying to load two files in a row.

> LoadWorker::file_filter contents:  point_filter.argc: 6
>   point_filter.args:  filter
>   -clip_z_above 12
>   -keep_intensity 11 222 Using filter:  filter
>   -clip_z_above 12
>   -keep_intensity 11 222 LoadWorker::file_filter contents:  point_filter.argc: 6 point_filter.args:  filter clip_z_above 2
>   keep_intensity 1 22 Using filter:  filter
>
> // 6 blank lines here

To make it even more odd, during the second run each string except the first one in `point_filter.args` is missing the first character and in the `argv` they are all empty.

Any clues whatsoever?

Comment: Does `parse` modify the `char*` passed?

Comment: I don't think it does. Will check. Still the `LoadWorker` object is deleted and created again every time a load button is pressed. So the contents of point_filter are created again from the `AdvancedLoadDialog::point_filter` which shouldn't change at all.

Comment: const_cast<char*>(it->c_str()) Never do that! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char

Comment: Turns out it was the `parse` function modifying the array. Should've checked that first. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be very, very cautious about doing things involving `std::string::c_str` as you are doing here:

```
argv.push_back(const_cast<char*>(it->c_str()));
```

If you want to keep the values provided by `c_str`, you should copy them into a new container first.

If [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) is to be trusted (which is not always the case),

> the values in this array should not be modified in the program and are only guaranteed to remain unchanged until the next call to a non-constant member function of the string object

Though I can't immediately put my hands on any more useful information from other sources.

Comment: I know. It returns a pointer to the memory location occupied by std::string, so I could get in trouble if this changed. However `point_filter.args` is a member of the `LoadWorker` created in constructor so it should not change for as long as the object exists. And additionally why would the strings in `point_filter.args ` got first characters missing. I assume c_str() can't cause that.

Answer (score 1):

In AdvancedLoadDialog, try pushing an allocated version of arg rather than an automatic version.  You appear to be pushing a reference to a variable that will be destructed upon leaving AdvancedDialogLoad.