# Cannot convert string to const char

Tags: c++, string, char, strlen

I have this function and the compiler yells at me saying "Cannot convert string to const char".

```
void 
DramaticLetters(string s, short TimeLength)
{
    for(int i = 0, sLen = strlen(s); i < sLen; i++){
        cout << s[i];
        Sleep(TimeLength);
    }
}
```

There's something wrong with the strlen, I think

Comment: Just use `s.length()` or `s.size()`. Strings don't implicitly convert to character arrays. If you really need one (which you don't for length), use `s.c_str()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char?rq=1

Comment: Just a general hint - if something goes wrong with standard functions, 99.99% of the time it's your fault.

Comment: Your un-use of the member functions makes me want to guide you to this [reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Look through and get a feel of what's available.

Comment: @Cubic: Exactly. I've had experiences where something *had* to have been an standard lib error, but that was an error in my code. Anything you think is a bug is most likely implementation defined behavior. Just read the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strlen()` is for C `const char*` strings. To get the length of a string `s`, use `s.size()` or `s.length()`. If you want to get a C string from a `string`, use `s.c_str()`.

Although C++ makes it *seem* that `const char*` and `string` are interchangeable, that only goes one way when converting `const char*` to `string`.

There is no reason why you would want to use `strlen` either. `strlen` is most likely defined with a loop, which will never be as efficiant as `size()`, which is most likley just a getter for a length property of the `string` class. Only convert `string` to C strings when calling C functions for which there is not a C++ alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You should not mix C and C++ string functions. Instead of `strlen()` (a C-style function), use [`string::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size):

```
for(int i = 0, sLen = s.size(); i < sLen; i++) {
    cout << s[i];
    Sleep(TimeLength);
}
```

Here you have a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) with all methods from class `string`.

Comment: So not all C functions can be used in C++?

Comment: @user1575615 C++ "reimplements" many of the C features (e.g., using class `std::string` instead of just a char array and `strlen`, `strcpy`, etc.). You can still use the C-style features, though. Actually you can make a C++ program that looks like a C one, but you should not mix C and C++ solutions, such as `std::string` (from C++) with `strlen`, `strcmp`, etc. (from C).

Answer (score 1):

As chris said in his comment, strlen is used for a `const char *`, whereas you're passing it a `string`. Instead of

```
for(int i = 0, sLen = strlen(s); i < sLen; i++){
    cout << s[i];
    Sleep(TimeLength);
}
```

Use this:

```
for(int i = 0, sLen = s.length(); i < sLen; i++){
    cout << s[i];
    Sleep(TimeLength);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strlen` operates on `char const *`. If you really wanted to, you could do `strlen(s.c_str())`, but `std::string` has a lot of functionality, including a `length()` method, which returns the number of characters in the string

Answer (score 0):

Few remarks:

- You do not modify the string within the function so better pass a const reference to it(const string& s)
- The string itself defines methods for getting its length - s.size() and s.length() both will work. Additional benefit is both this methods are constant with respect to complexity as opposed to the linear complexity of strlen
- If you REALLY want to use strlen use s.c_str(): `strlen(s.c_str())`