# How do you convert string to c_str() in this situation?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert std::string to const char* or char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

My code is this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string mapChange(int side, string oldMap);

int main(){

  string createMapName;
  string createMapNameData [10];
  int featureSelect;

  cout << "(1)Game or (2)Mapmaker";
  cin >> featureSelect;

  if(featureSelect == 2)
  {
    cout << "Name of Map?";
    cin >> createMapName;
    ofstream mapName;
    mapName.open (createMapName);
    mapName << createMapNameData[0] << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

string mapChange(int side, string oldMap){

    string newMap;
    if(oldMap == "Test")
    {
      cout << "Map Found :D";
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "ERROR MAP NOT FOUND, PLEASE REINSTALL.";
    }
    return newMap;
}
```

How do I use a c_str instread of string on line 15 i.e. how do I convert string to c_str()?
Please help,
Lijrobert

Comment: Do you mean mapName.open(createMapName.c_str()); ?

Comment: may be, `createMapName.c_str()` ?

Comment: wait can you just convert it like this: createMapName.c_str() ?

Comment: Yes it really is that simple.

Comment: @user68537 this is because using implicit conversions is not a very good programming style in c++, thats why std::string uses c_str()

Comment: I'm unsure why this differs from any of the previous questions.

Comment: line 15 is `cin >> featureSelect;`?