# convert string to char*

Tags: c++, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert std::string to const char* or char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

Probably a & or something similar missing (I am noob at cpp).

I have

```
string R = "somthing";
char*  S;
```

How would I copy `R` into `S`

Comment: Why has this question been down voted twice?

Comment: @john: Maybe some people thought that this is a duplicate of another question, or they thought that this question shows no effort, I don't really know. For a beginner this isn't an obvious question, but I don't expect a comment from the downvoters in this case, since it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Zeta Maybe but the downvotes appeared before any indication of the duplication. Seems like bad manners to me.

Answer (score 45):

There are many ways. Here are at least five:

```
/*
 * An example of converting std::string to (const)char* using five
 * different methods. Error checking is emitted for simplicity.
 *
 * Compile and run example (using gcc on Unix-like systems):
 *
 *  $ g++ -Wall -pedantic -o test ./test.cpp
 *  $ ./test
 *  Original string (0x7fe3294039f8): hello
 *  s1 (0x7fe3294039f8): hello
 *  s2 (0x7fff5dce3a10): hello
 *  s3 (0x7fe3294000e0): hello
 *  s4 (0x7fe329403a00): hello
 *  s5 (0x7fe329403a10): hello
 */

#include <alloca.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::string s0;
    const char *s1;
    char *s2;
    char *s3;
    char *s4;
    char *s5;

    // This is the initial C++ string.
    s0 = "hello";

    // Method #1: Just use "c_str()" method to obtain a pointer to a
    // null-terminated C string stored in std::string object.
    // Be careful though because when `s0` goes out of scope, s1 points
    // to a non-valid memory.
    s1 = s0.c_str();

    // Method #2: Allocate memory on stack and copy the contents of the
    // original string. Keep in mind that once a current function returns,
    // the memory is invalidated.
    s2 = (char *)alloca(s0.size() + 1);
    memcpy(s2, s0.c_str(), s0.size() + 1);

    // Method #3: Allocate memory dynamically and copy the content of the
    // original string. The memory will be valid until you explicitly
    // release it using "free". Forgetting to release it results in memory
    // leak.
    s3 = (char *)malloc(s0.size() + 1);
    memcpy(s3, s0.c_str(), s0.size() + 1);

    // Method #4: Same as method #3, but using C++ new/delete operators.
    s4 = new char[s0.size() + 1];
    memcpy(s4, s0.c_str(), s0.size() + 1);

    // Method #5: Same as 3 but a bit less efficient..
    s5 = strdup(s0.c_str());

    // Print those strings.
    printf("Original string (%p): %s\n", s0.c_str(), s0.c_str());
    printf("s1 (%p): %s\n", s1, s1);
    printf("s2 (%p): %s\n", s2, s2);
    printf("s3 (%p): %s\n", s3, s3);
    printf("s4 (%p): %s\n", s4, s4);
    printf("s5 (%p): %s\n", s5, s5);

    // Release memory...
    free(s3);
    delete [] s4;
    free(s5);
}
```

Comment: c_str() creates const char *  rather than char *

Answer (score 19):

First of all, you would have to allocate memory:

```
char * S = new char[R.length() + 1];
```

then you can use [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) with `S` and `R.c_str()`:

```
std::strcpy(S,R.c_str());
```

You can also use `R.c_str()` if the string doesn't get changed or the c string is only used once. However, if `S` is going to be modified, you should copy the string, as writing to [`R.c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) results in undefined behavior.

Note: Instead of `strcpy` you can also use `str::copy`.

Comment: <string>.c_str() is great for reading the string as a char* type just once for some sort of processing.