# Reading a shader from a .txt file using a structure

Tags: c++, opengl, struct, shader

I've started learning how to use OpenGL and I absolutely hate having my shaders declared as global variables before my main().

I thought it would be cool to make a structure or class that would read the shader from a file in my project directory. The file reading works perfectly fine, but for some reason it won't actually output an image like it would if I had the shader declared before main. Here is my example.

**Shader Reading Structure:**

```
#include "allHeader.h"

struct shaderReader
{
    shaderReader::shaderReader(std::string);
    const GLchar* source;
};


shaderReader::shaderReader(std::string name)
{
std::string line, allLines;
std::ifstream theFile(name);
if (theFile.is_open())
{
    while (std::getline(theFile, line))
    {
        allLines = allLines + line + "\n";
    }

    source = allLines.c_str();
    std::cout << source;

    theFile.close();
}
else
    {
    std::cout << "Unable to open file.";
    }
}
```

**Snapshot of Area right before main()**

```
shaderReader vertexShader = shaderReader("vertex.txt");
shaderReader fragmentShader = shaderReader("fragment.txt");

const GLchar* vertexSource =
"#version 150 core\n"
"in vec2 position;"
"void main() {"
"   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);"
"}";
const GLchar* fragmentSource =
"#version 150 core\n"
"out vec4 outColor;"
"void main() {"
"   outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);"
"}";

int main()
{
     //stuff
}
```

**Works**

```
    GLuint vertexShaderObject = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShaderObject, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShaderObject);

    //Now let's create the Fragment Shader Object
    GLuint fragmentShaderObject = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShaderObject, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShaderObject);
```

**Doesn't work for some Reason**

```
    const GLchar* ob1 = vertexShader.source;
    const GLchar* ob2 = fragmentShader.source;
    GLuint vertexShaderObject = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShaderObject, 1, &ob1, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShaderObject);

    //Now let's create the Fragment Shader Object
    GLuint fragmentShaderObject = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShaderObject, 1, &ob2, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShaderObject);
```

**Also Doesn't Work**

```
    GLuint vertexShaderObject = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShaderObject, 1, &vertexShader.source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShaderObject);

    //Now let's create the Fragment Shader Object
    GLuint fragmentShaderObject = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShaderObject, 1, &fragmentShader.source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShaderObject);
```

The above code when working prints out a white triangle in the middle of a black screen. However, when not working I just get a black screen. I tried checking the shaders for compile errors and I got no errors at all. I'm think perhaps something is wrong within the structure, something there I didn't do right. Thank you for reading my question, if you had a similar problem I hope my question helps you.

Comment: You let the `allLines` string go out of scope after you finished reading the code. So the memory containing the shader code will be freed before you use it.

Comment: Put the shaders into `.txt` files.  Wrap each line in `""` at the start and end.  End it with a `;`.  Then `const GLChar* some_shader =`, newline, `#include "shader.txt"`.  Hey look!  Compile time string, no file loading at runtime, and your shaders are out of the way?

Comment: Hey, @RetoKoradi how exactly did `allLines` go out of scope?
@Yakk could you demonstrate an example as an answer if possible, thank you.

Comment: @BryantheLion You declare `allLines` in the constructor. So when the constructor ends `allLines` is destroyed.

Comment: But don't I copy all of the information in `allLines` into `source` before the constructor ends? I verified what both of you are saying, and you're both absolutely correct, however, I'm having an issue understanding why since I thought I had successfully copied `allLines` to `source`.

Comment: You don't copy the content of `allLines` into `source`. You get a pointer to the internal data of `allLines`, and assign that pointer to `source`. Then when `allLines` goes out of scope at the end of the constructor, it frees its memory, and `source` is now pointing to freed memory.

Comment: I understand now, my mistake was not being clear on what c_str() was actually doing.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a mix of C++ (`std::string`) and C (`char*`) strings in an invalid way.

In the constructor, you're building up the code in a C++ `string`, which is an object that automatically allocates and re-allocates the memory to hold the string data as the string grows. It will also automatically free that data when it goes out of scope at the end of the constructor.

The root of the problem is here:

```
source = allLines.c_str();
```

where `source` is a class/struct member. The `c_str()` method on the `string` gives you a pointer to the internal string data of the object. As explained above, this data is freed when `allLines` goes out of scope at the end of the `shaderReader` constructor, so you end up with a pointer to freed memory. This results in undefined behavior, because this memory could now be used for something else.

The cleanest way to fix this is to use C++ strings consistently. Change the struct definition to:

```
struct shaderReader
{
    shaderReader::shaderReader(std::string);
    std::string source;
};
```

Then in the constructor, you can read the source code directly into this class member:

```
while (std::getline(theFile, line))
{
    source = source + line + "\n";
}
```

The only reason why you have to bother with a `char*` is because `glShaderSource()` needs one. The safest approach is to convert this at the last moment:

```
const GLchar* ob1 = vertexShader.source.c_str();
GLuint vertexShaderObject = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vertexShaderObject, 1, &ob1, NULL);
glCompileShader(vertexShaderObject);
```

This way, you only use the pointer to the internal `string` data very temporarily, and you don't have to bother with C-style strings and memory management otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, this is actually very smart and I'm not sure why I didn't think about doing something like this before. This is probably the best method presented here.

Comment: I tried doing something a bit different which **should** work but I get a Debug Assertion Failed. All I did was created a new variable `const GLchar* Source` in my struct definition. Then after the `while` loop I simply made `Source = source.c_str()` and in my function `glShaderSource(vertexShaderObject, 1, &vertexShader.Source, NULL);`

It works but when I close the application it gives me that error.

Comment: Nevermind, the reason was because I had kept the old destructor definition. `if(source)
{
    delete[] source;
    source = nullptr;
}`

Comment: @reto-koradi

I tried converting your idea into a function but it crashes the opengl context when trying this ( consider fragment being a "string" that read a shader from a txt). I suspect I'm simply doing something stupid with the pointers. I can guarantee the string contains an usable shader. -------------------------------------------------------- glShaderSource(vertexShaderObject, 1, getFragmentShaderSrc(), NULL); ->using this function: ----------------------> const GLchar * const * getFragmentShaderSrc(){ const GLchar* d = fragment.c_str(); return &d; }

Answer (score 1):

change

```
source = allLines.c_str();
```

into

```
source = new char[allLines.length()+1];
strcpy(source,allLines.c_str());
```

And in the destructor of shaderReader, release the memory allocated for source

```
if(source)
{
    delete[] source;
    source = nullptr;
}
```

Ref:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12862777/3427520

Comment: This is good, I simply had to tweak it a bit in order to convert the `char*` to `const GLchar*`, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Any Idea why defining my destructor is causing a Debug Assertion Failed?

Comment: Why are you suggesting to store the code in a C string if the OP is using C++, and is already using C++ strings in the rest of the code?

Comment: Er, I'm sorry I missed that... Yes, your answer is better.

Comment: @BryantheLion Maybe you delete the memory of the allLines.c_str() accidentally, which will cause an Assertion failure.

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to store your shader in a `std::vector<GLchar>` so you don't need to worry about allocating and deallocating memory:

Maybe something like this:

```
struct shaderReader
{
    shaderReader(std::string);
    std::vector<GLchar> source;
    const GLchar* data;
    GLint size;
};

shaderReader::shaderReader(std::string name)
{
    std::string line, allLines;
    std::ifstream theFile(name);
    if(theFile.is_open())
    {
        while(std::getline(theFile, line))
        {
            allLines = allLines + line + "\n";
        }

        source.assign(allLines.begin(), allLines.end());
        size = source.size();
        data = source.data();

        theFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file.";
    }
}

int main()
{
    shaderReader sr("fragment-shader.txt");
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &sr.data, &sr.size);
}
```