# GLSL Shader (compilation error)

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've read all recommended posts, I've tried those solutions, but non of them helped.

In short problem lies in the third argument of

```
glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
```

This code work:

```
const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 120 \n"
                         "attribute vec3 pos;\n"
                         "attribute vec2 texCoord;\n"
                         "varying vec2 texCoord0;\n"
                         "uniform mat4 transform;\n"
                         "void main()\n"
                         "{\n"
                         "   gl_Position = transform * vec4(pos, 1.0);\n"
                         "   texCoord0 = texCoord;\n"
                        "}\0";
```

But I want to read it from a file, following code works

```
std::string s= "vertex";
std::ifstream file(s.c_str());
std::stringstream buffer;

buffer << file.rdbuf();
std::string str = buffer.str();
std::cout << str;
```

And is outputing:

```
#version 120
attribute vec3 pos;
attribute vec2 texCoord;
varying vec2 texCoord0;
uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = transform * vec4(pos, 1.0);
    texCoord0 = texCoord;
}
```

I know that I cannot just simply convert string with code like this:

```
const char *vertexShaderSource = str.c_str();
```

And pass it into: `glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);`
So I've used following code to prevent it from ceasing to exist:

```
char * writable = new char[str.size() + 1];
std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), writable);
writable[str.size()] = '\0';
```

Passing `glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &writable, NULL);`does not work also.
I'm getting following error all the time, even with another copy&paste code from tutorials

```
 0:1(4): preprocessor error: syntax error, unexpected HASH_TOKEN
```

What else I can do?

I've read these posts:
[Reading a shader from a .txt file using a structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794981/reading-a-shader-from-a-txt-file-using-a-structure?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[read GLSL shaders from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842617/read-glsl-shaders-from-file?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: my bet is you have some nasty control code (ASCII code <32)  messing up the compilation try to save the string as file and then see it in hex view and look for characters below 20h (not counting `0Ah, 0Dh, 09h` which are valid CR,LF,Tab). btw I am missing `+` between the substrings but that is most likely just because I used different compiler anyway maybe some macro encapsulation of the strings would solve your problem.

Comment: In hex view everythings seems to be ok

Comment: then I would try to do everything in single line and use `\r\n` instead of `\n` if it make a difference. Also Some compilers requires to use `_T("text")` instead of `"text"` otherwise they convert it to unicode or different encoding messing up the stuff at least I saw people use that in such cases here in SO...

Comment: Same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50769270/converting-text-string-into-const-char-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use to load shader sources:

```
ifstream iStream(filename);
stringstream buffer;
buffer << iStream.rdbuf();
string source = buffer.str();

const char* sources[] = { source.c_str() };
glShaderSource(handle, 1, sources, 0);
```

As you can see, the `string` can be given directly to `glShaderSource`; there is no need to create a copy of it. Have a look at the spec for [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) if you're not convinced.

Not sure what the problem is in your case. I have used both `\r\n` and `\n` line endings successfully. Maybe you have a [`U+FEFF` BOM character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of the file? It could with the the "hash" mentioned in the compilation error.