# converting std::string to char *

Tags: c++, string, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert std::string to const char* or char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

I have a `std::string` and want to pass that as a file name to fstream like

```
std::string fname = "/home/mahmood/filter" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(b) + ".txt";
std::fstream fout (fname, std::fstream::app | std::fstream::out);
```

but I get an error for the second line

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char>   >::basic_fstream(std::string&,
```

Seems that it can not convert `string` to `char *`. Also casting doesn't work

Comment: Would it be so hard to google?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `fname.c_str()` as:

```
std::fstream fout (fname.c_str(), std::fstream::app | std::fstream::out);
```

`.c_str()`returns `const char*`. In C++03, you've to pass `const char*`.

In C++11, you [can pass](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream) `std::string` but it seems your compiler doesn't support it.