# Function to trim non, alphabetic, numeric characters from character array

Tags: c++, char

I am looking to make a C++ function that has the following prototype:

```
char *trim(char *string)
```

What I want this function to do is the following:

- Trim all the non, alphabetic, numeric characters
- If there is a space encountered, it is to trim the space and the appending characters
- Return the trimmed character array

Example:

Input: `*&^!@^ThisIsA#Test String;'{><,.`

Output: `ThisIsATest`

Comment: Did you mean `std::string trim(char const * str)`?

Comment: definitely can find trim in SO

Comment: Well, interresting, good luck then.

Comment: Well I see now how vague my question was, so I edit it. Hope it makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way, performance wise, but it is the most logical way to me. `copy_if` seem to not exist.  But looking at ASCII table [www.asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/) I loop through the character array and only copy the alphabetic numeric character to my string object, and until I find a space or reach the array's end.

```
char *trim(char *str)
{
    std::size_t len = strlen(str);

    string temp = "";

    for (size_t k = 0; k < len; k++)
    {
            // If space found end the process
            if(str[k] == 32)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if ((str[k] >= 48) && (str[k] >= 57)) // numbers
            {
                temp += str[k];
            }
            else if ((str[k] >= 65) && (str[k] >= 90)) // uppercase letters
            {
                temp += str[k];
            }
            else if ((str[k] >= 97) && (str[k] >= 122)) // lowercase letters
            {
                temp += str[k];
            }
    }

    // Convert String to char*
    char * writable = new char[temp.size() + 1];
    std::copy(temp.begin(), temp.end(), writable);
    writable[temp.size()] = '\0';

    return writable;
}
```

Got the idea to convert string to char* from here [convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

Answer (score 3):

One option is `std::copy_if` to copy the good characters to a return buffer:

```
char *trim(const char *str) {
    std::size_t len = strlen(str);

    char *ret = new char[len + 1]{}; //allocate space and initialize
    std::copy_if(
        str, //from beginning
        std::find(str, str + len, ' '), //to first space (or end)
        ret, //copy to beginning of buffer
        isalnum //the alphanumeric characters
    );

    return ret; //return the buffer
}

int main() {
    std::cout << trim("ab$#h%#.s354,.23nj%f abcsf"); //abhs35423njf
    std::cout << trim("adua9d8f9hs.f,lere.r"); //adua9d8f9hsflerer
}
```

Notice how my example completely ignores the fact that you have to deallocate the memory you allocated in `trim`, which is ok in this case because the program ends right after. I strongly suggest you change it to use `std::string` instead. It both eases the definition of `trim` because of the `std::begin` and `std::end` compatibility, and manages the memory for you.

Comment: You need to cast to select the right overload of `isalnum()`. I agree with `string` it’s nicer: `copy_if(s.begin(), find(s.begin(), s.end(), ' '), back_inserter(result), static_cast<int(*)(int)>(isalnum));` or more generally `find_if()` with `isspace()`.

Comment: @JonPurdy, Are you sure you need to cast it? GCC gave me nothing. Anyway, I did think about `isspace`, and I agree it's a suitable replacement. I was kind of just going with the wording of the question, but it's a good mention.

Comment: I had to cast on Ideone. I included the header as `<cctype>`, though; if you used `<ctype.h>` then the behaviour might differ.

Comment: @JonPurdy, I used `<cctype>` as well. It's 4.7.2, for reference. All VS11 gives me is the usual warning for it possibly not being safe (though it should be in this case), and it looks like http://llvm.org/demo doesn't have `copy_if`.

Comment: @chris current errors I am getting "C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'" for this line `char *ret = new char[len + 1]{};` and "C2039: 'copy_if' : is not a member of 'std'". I am testing in VS, but will deploy it on a IMB mid rage machine

Comment: @ZioN, You need to include `<algorithm>` if you haven't, and `std::copy_if` is C++11. What else is C++11 is the initializer for the array. You can just stick a 0 in there for that one.

Comment: @ZioN, There's also a pretty good implementation of it [here](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2001/01/8022.php).