# convert from string to char* - passing function pointer

Tags: c++, string, pointers, parameter-passing

this post bases on the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char), a post on SO

I write a function to get a given file extension (string type), something like:

```
void GetFileExtension(string filename, char* extension)
{
    vector<string> rec;

    StrDelimit(filename, '.', rec);

    //cout << rec[rec.size()-2].c_str()[1] << endl;

    //extension = rec[rec.size()-2].c_str()[0];

    //extension = &rec[rec.size()-2].c_str()[0];

    string str = rec[rec.size()-2];

    // conversion from string to char*
    vector<char> writable(str.size() + 1);

    std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), writable.begin());

    //cout << writable << endl;

    extension = &writable[0];
}
```

StrDelimit works fine already which receives a string and delimits to vector of substrings by the given delimiter

I use the "//conversion from string to char*"  as shown to return the result to calling main program

There is no compile error but the result is a string of meaningless characters. What's it the problem?

any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

char *extension is a *temporary* copy of the address of a string. To actually put new data into it, you'd have to copy data to the address that it holds.

Does this help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void getStringInoExistingBufer(char* existingBufferOut)
{
    strcpy(existingBufferOut, "someData");
}

void getStringIntoNonExistingBuffer(char **newBufferOut)
{
    *newBufferOut = strdup("someOtherData");
}

int main()
{
    char buffer1[100] = {};
    char *buffer2 = NULL;

    printf("buffer1 (before): '%s'\n", buffer1);
    getStringInoExistingBufer(buffer1);
    printf("buffer1 (after): '%s'\n", buffer1);

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("buffer2 (before): '%s'\n", buffer2);
    getStringIntoNonExistingBuffer(&buffer2);
    printf("buffer2 (after): '%s'\n", buffer2);
}
```

**Output:**

```
buffer1 (before): ''
buffer1 (after): 'someData'


buffer2 (before): '(null)'
buffer2 (after): 'someOtherData'
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is you creating the data member `writable` on the stack, and then point to it with `extension` BUT the scope of writable is the function meaning that when the function returns `writable` is been cleared leaving `extension` pointing nothing.

you can allocated a dynamic buffer for the char* but that is more C approach than C++.
If possible I would recommend changing the function type to return a string or a vector which will make it much easier, and you can change those types to char* whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just return extension as `std::string`?

For example:

```
std::string GetFileExtension(std::string filename)
{
    std::vector<string> rec;

    StrDelimit(filename, '.', rec);

    std::string extension = rec[rec.size() - 2];
    return extension;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're not really returning anything;

```
void GetFileExtension(string filename, char* extension)
{
    ...
    extension = &writable[0];  // Assignment to local variable
}
```

If you intend to update the char* passed in `extension`, you'll need to pass it as a `char**` (i.e. a pointer to your `char*`).

Secondly, even if you fix that, you're attempting to return a pointer to data in a local variable;

```
void GetFileExtension(string filename, char* extension)
{
    ...
    vector<char> writable(str.size() + 1);   // Local variable
    ...
    extension = &writable[0];       // writable disappears after this line
                                    // and extension will point to invalid memory
}
```

Just returning an `std::string` would simplify your code quite a bit.