# Cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘const char*

Tags: c++

What is wrong with this code?

```
string s = getString(); // Return string

if(!strcmp(s, "STRING")) {
    // Do something
}
```

While compiling, I am getting the error like:

> error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int strcmp(const char*, const char*)’|

Comment: You want `if ( s == "STRING" )`. `strcmp` is the `const char*` version. (You could use `if (!strcmp(s.c_str(), "STRING")`, but don't).

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `strcmp` to see what arguments it accepts? Why do you even use `strcmp` like that when you already have an `std::string` that defines `operator==`?

Comment: @BoBTFish `(s == "STRING")` in this case.

Comment: @BoBTFish  Yes I want to compare s with "STRING"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert std::string to const char\* or char\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

Comment: @Rakkun: that's not good practice... the `std::string` type overloads comparison to a `const char*` to avoid creating a `std::string` temporary as your suggested code does....

Comment: The beauty of `C++`: Where `string == "foo"` means exactly what it says.

Comment: The beauty of C: Where string == "foo" means exactly what it means :-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`strcmp` accepts `const char*` as argument. You can use `c_str` method:

```
if(!strcmp(s.c_str(),"STRING"))
```

Or just use overloaded `operator==` for `std::string`:

```
if(s == "STRING")
```

Comment: I am going to use if (s == "STRING") , but instead of this can I use if(getString() =="STRING")

Comment: My code is just like this http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=rDcPApix And if do like this if (s == "STRING") I am getting the result.

Comment: Your code works for me. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3b624c795e449d52abf0b16ac5711e7f-7f4bc2c90970fdf19c48ebf8cc2bae3f)

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. That was my coding problem, any way I solved it.

Answer (score 12):

You need to use `s.c_str()` to get the C string version of a `std::string`, along the lines of:

```
if (!strcmp (s.c_str(), "STRING")) ...
```

but I'm not sure why you wouldn't just use:

```
if (s == "STRING") ...
```

which is a lot more readable.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `c_str()` method on `std::string` as in the other answers.

You can also just do this:

```
if (s == "STRING") { ... }
```

Which is clearer and doesn't pretend that you're writing C.

Answer (score 2):

You must use the [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) member function of `std::string` that gives you the underlying `char` array, if you want to keep the C way of comparing strings.

Otherwise, you should use the `operator==` which can test equality between strings and `const char*`.

Answer (score 1):

You must use c_str() and it should solve your problem.

Comment: That is one way, but it is the worse way.