# Unable to return the contents of a vector<char> as a char* pointer

Tags: c++

I am trying to store a char* into a struct's char* field. I have tried different things but none of them worked. The problematic piece of code is shown below:

pInfo is the object of the struct PlayerInfo.

```
PlayerInfo *pInfo = (PlayerInfo*)malloc(sizeof(PlayerInfo));
```

The char* I get from GetAddress is stored in the Address field of PlayerInfo.

```
pInfo->Address = GetAddress(pInfo->playerId);
```

The GetAddress function is shown below. It converts integers to strings, stores them in a vector and returns the vector as a char* using &retChar[0].

```
char* GetAddress(int playerId)
{
  std::string strPlayerId = std::to_string(playerId);
  std::string strGroupId = std::to_string(group.GetGroupId());
  std::string retAddress = strPlayerId + ":" + strGroupId + ":" + GenRandomChar();

  //From -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char
  std::vector<char> retChar(retAddress.begin(), retAddress.end());
  retChar.push_back('\0');

  for(std::vector<char>::const_iterator i = retChar.begin(); i != retChar.end(); ++i)
      std::cout << "retChar is " << *i << std::endl;
  return &retChar[0];
}
```

When I print the contents, only garbage is printed. I tried printing the memory contents from gdb, but that also did not help.

```
char* address = GetAddress(pInfo->playerId);
std::cout << "address is " << *address << std::endl;
std::cout << "address is " << pInfo->Address << std::endl;
std::cout << "address is " << *(pInfo->Address) << std::endl;
```

Comment: have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` and not `new`?  Second, you are returning a pointer to data which is cleaned up by `vector` when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize that. I think I will just pass a reference and store the contents of the vector into the reference.

Comment: @Sarvavyapi a reference won't necessarily help you need to do some memory management - the easiest way is to make the field in PlayerInfo a std::string or if need a vector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that your function scope local variable

```
 std::vector<char> retChar;
```

goes out of scope and is destroyed after your function returned.

Thus using the returned pointer `return &retChar[0];` is calling undefined behavior.

The better choice would be to pass the pointer where to copy the data as a reference

```
 void GetAddress(int playerId, char*& result) {

     std::vector<char> retChar;
     // ...

     std::copy(retChar.begin(),result);
 }
```

and ensure `result` buffer is big enough to receive the copied data.

**NOTE:**
The above suggestion just solves the 1st level of your current problem. The probably better idea is to change your function simply to deal with `std::string` instead of using `std::vector<char>` and raw `char*` pointers (if your use case allows to refactor this):

Make `PlayerInfo::Address` member a `std::string` type

```
struct PlayerInfo {
    // ...
    std::string Address;
};
```

and define your `GetAddress()` function as follows

```
std::string GetAddress(int playerId) {
  std::ostringstream result;
  result << playerId << ":" group.GetGroupId() << ":" << GenRandomChar();
  return result.str();
}
```

and use the results `std::string::c_str()` method if you really need a `const char*` value to pass it elsewhere.

Comment: The problem is stated correctly in that the char* points to something unknown but the better fix is to pass back a vector and only get char* when needed i.e. to pass to a C function - Then the vector does all the memory management

Comment: Well std::vector<char> is still a reasonable thing to use - depends on the use

Comment: @Mark _'depends on the use'_ Of course, but what it sounds from the OP's usage `std::string` is appropriate. I'll put another update clarifying (otherwise I mentioned _'(if your use case allows to refactor this)'_).

Comment: Yes, I can refactor the code to use a string instead of a char*. This is a personal project and I wanted to try out all such scenarios so that I learn and become comfortable with them.

Comment: @Sarvavyapi Well, then the final answer might help you to proceed successfully ;) Glad to help if I could ...

Answer (score 3):

I think the idea of using `std::vector<char>` in the selected answer to [How to convert a std::string to const char* or char*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char) is that the `std::vector<char>` *is* your writable character array, not that you should extract a `char *` from it.  (You can, however, *copy* the contents into a different memory location identified by a `char *`, as you have already seen.)

But I would ask why you are storing a `char *` in the `Address` member of `PlayerInfo`.  Why don't you make that member an `std::string` and change the return type of `getAddress()` to `std::string`, in which case `getAddress` can simply return `retAddress`?

Alternatively, you can declare `getAddress` like this: `void getAddress(int playerId, std::string& retAddress)` and the code inside the function is even simpler, because you don't have to declare `retAddress` as a local variable inside the function.