# how convert string to xmlChar

Tags: c++, type-conversion, libxml2

I'm trying to convert a string to an xmlChar.  The compiler says no suitable conversion function from const string to xmlChar exists.  This is what the code looks like:

```
bool ClassName::openFile(const String& ZipFile)
{
    //convert 
    const xmlChar *temp = (const xmlChar)ZipFile; //ZipFile has an error here. ZipFile is path and filename
    ...
}
```

Any ideas?  I googled it and people were converting from xmlChar to string but not this direction.

Comment: Possibly `const xmlChar *temp = (const xmlChar*)(ZipFile.c_str());`

Comment: using C style cast with C++ is frowned upon as being poor coding style since it is a source of defects. I suspect you wanted to do something like `const xmlChar *temp = (const xmlChar *)ZipFile.c_str();`? see  [how to convert a std::string to const char or char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

Comment: This is impossible to answer unless you provide the definitions of String and xmlChar, too.

Comment: xmlChar is part of libxml2.  Thanks to @Christophe for editing the tags. What R Sahu and Richard Chambers suggested was a great help.  I'm all set.  Thanks! string is std::string for us.

Comment: string temp1 = "hello";
const xmlChar *temp = (const xmlChar *)temp1.c_str();

Answer (score 3):

`xmlChar` is just a typedef of `unsigned char`. Just make your sentence like this:

```
const xmlChar *temp = ZipFile.c_str();
```

Answer (score 0):

unsafe but removed overhead.

```
xmlChar *temp = reinterpret_cast<xmlChar*>(ZipFile);
```

but you must be aware of usage of **reinterpret_cast**

Answer (score 0):

This xml library was written for standard C. There are c style casting methods used at the time that took advantage of the BAD_CAST keyword in the library. Example:

```
rc = xmlTextWriterWriteElement(writer, BAD_CAST "Value1", BAD_CAST "DATA1");
if (rc < 0) {
    throw EXCEPTION("Error in xmlTextWriterWriteElement");
}
```

But with c++ if you want to avoid the c-style cast the best you can do is:

```
rc = xmlTextWriterWriteElement(writer, const_cast<xmlChar*>(reinterpret_cast<const xmlChar *>("Value1")), const_cast<xmlChar*>(reinterpret_cast<const xmlChar *>("DATA1")));
```

Note that the usual dangers of this casting aren't a problem due to the use case here. We can safely assume the underlying library isn't going to do anything nasty to us.