# what is the difference between a[0] and &a[0] in string

Tags: c++, string

```
string a = "asdf";
cout<<&a[0];
cout<<a[0];
```

Why are these two outputs different? Why is `&a[0]` not the address but the whole string?

Comment: You are getting the underlying `char *` inside that string as explained in detail in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4152881/2458319)

Answer (score 13):

`&a[0]` has type `char *`. Stream operator `<<` is deliberately overloaded for `const char *` arguments to output zero-terminated string (C-style string) that begins at that address. E.g. if you do

```
const char *p = "Hello World!";
cout << p;
```

it is that overloaded version of `<<` that makes sure the `"Hello World!"` string itself is sent to output, not the pointer value.

And this is exactly what makes your code to output the entire string as well. Since C++11 `std::string` objects are required to store their data as zero-terminated strings and `&a[0]` is nothing else than a pointer to the beginning of the string stored inside your `a` object.

Comment: Addendum: Using `&a[0]` instead of `a` is less performant and cannot cope with embedded zeroes...

Answer (score 1):

When printing a pointer to a standard library output stream, if it's `char*` or `const char*`, the null-terminated string pointed to will be printed, rather than the address itself. If you want to have the address printed:

```
cout << static_cast<const void*>(&a[0]);
```

(Trivia: if the pointer type isn't convertible to `const void*` either---because it is a function pointer or a pointer to member or it is volatile---then it is converted to `bool`.)

Answer (score 1):

`&a[0]` yields type `char*`. This is a type for which `operator<<()` is overloaded. This particular overload prints the characters starting at the address until it finds a null-character, `'\0'`. It won't print the address like you'd expect.

Since you need the address, there's `std::addressof()` in the standard library:

```
std::cout << std::addressof(a[0]);
```

you can also cast to `void*` which is almost like the above variant:

```
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(&a[0]);
```

Comment: `std::addressof(a[0])` is exactly the same as `&a[0]` here, right?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, they both have the same effect. But `std::addressof()` won't consider overloaded `operator&` for user-defined types.