# How to convert char* to double?

Tags: c++

I've tried two methods to convert my `char*` type `ss`
to a double type.
Here is my code(Compiled in VC++6.0  windows64-bit )

```
int main()
{
    char *ss = "-1964734.544";
    cout<<ss<<endl;
    cout<<*reinterpret_cast<double*>(ss)<<endl;
    cout<<*(double *)ss<<endl;
}
```

The results are:

```
-1964734.544
3.06123e-057
3.06123e-057
```

I'm not clear what is wrong and how to convert a `char*` to double.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a std::string to const char\* or char\*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

Comment: looks like you are confusing pointers with data

Comment: Hello @hashtabe_0 and welcome to SO. Your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char

Comment: MSVC 6.0 still runs under 64-bit Windows? You really want to update to a C++ compiler (you know, one developed after C++ was first standardized). It is difficult to give an answer that will work for such an old compiler, because I don't think the usual, standard-conforming ways work with it. Or at least not all, and not the ones you'd use in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strtod` like this: `double smth=strtod(ss,NULL,10);`

It's possible to use a bit different syntax. See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/) for an example.

Answer (score 7):

your issue here is that **A CAST IS NOT A CONVERSION**:

```
char *ss = "-1964734.544";
cout<<ss<<endl;
cout<<*reinterpret_cast<double*>(ss)<<endl;
cout<<*(double *)ss<<endl;
```

is that you're converting a string of characters into a number. What that means is that your memory is containing numbers being ascii values:

```
"-1964734.544"
```

is stored in memory as:

```
45, 49, 57, 54, 52, 55, 51, 52, 46, 53, 52, 52
```

which is in binary becomes:

```
00101101,00110001,00111001,00110110,00110100,00110111,00110011,00110100,00101110,00110101,00110100,00110100
```

within the memory. When converting to double, you're forcing the compiler to consider those numbers being read differently, which is following the [IEEE754 way for doubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985). And then 45,49,57,52 means something totally different using that encoding of numbers.

Then, considering chars are 8bits and double 32bits, after a cast your memory is then mapped the following way:

```
00101101001100010011100100110110,
00110100001101110011001100110100,
00101110001101010011010000110100
```

Then doing a "manual" interpretation to IEEE754 you get three floats:

```
1.0073988518377597E-11
1.7061830703823944E-7
4.120100094429091E-11
```

Which oddly is matching none of your values, so your memory sizes could be different, or some magic is happening during the casts.

The good way is to not reinterpret the memory, but to convert the value, and a good solution is to use [`strtod()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod) from C, or [`stod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/) from the standard library of C++. You'll find many ways to handle the conversion in the other answers or from the posts that duplicates this one.

If you want to have more fun with that just try [floats on that webpage](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should use `std::stod` function (C++11) with a more modern compiler

```
double result = std::stod(ss);
```

or, alternatively, use a `std::stringstream` from `<sstream>`

```
std::stringstream sstrm(ss);
double d;
sstrm >> d;
```

Comment: You didn't see the bit about VC++ 6.0, right? :P This would be a decent answer to a slightly different question, though.

Comment: @Wintermute I saw it but frankly I had no idea about the version number :)

Comment: VC++ 6.0 was released in 1998 (i.e., it was developed pre-standard, and that showed). Mind you, you're not alone in this, looking at the other answers. It's not something you expect to see in 2015.

Answer (score -1):

If You use cast then You treat pointer data as double value and this is wrong as pointer is an integer number representing the address in memory, You need to interpret data pointed to by `char*` to get the proper result, use `sscanf`, `atof` or other functions that take `char*` and give `double`

Answer (score -1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272023%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Use `atof(const char*)`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double pi;
    const char * str = "3.14";

    pi = atof(str);

    cout << pi << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @harper did you check the link in my post? Look at the prototype for `atof`