# How do I rename a file with a string using the rename() function (c++)?

Tags: c++, string, file, rename

Here is my code:

```
    rename("tmp.png", Filename);
```

The 2nd argument in the rename function is a string.(The user decides what the name is)
How do I properly code this so that tmp.png is renamed to whatever the user types?

My instructor says to use c_str somehow, But I'm not sure how.

This is my first post, Let me know if it's hard yo understand or If I'm asking it wrong somehow..

Comment: There's also this thing called Google search. It's great, check it out!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a std::string to const char\* or char\*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what to search on google, I'm a complete  beginner with programming, so please forgive me. I'll try harder with Google next time before asking..  Thanks

Answer (score 10):

It's hard to say, but have you tried that:

```
rename("tmp.png", Filename.c_str());
```

If `Filename` is a `std::string` `std::string::c_str()` converts it to a `const char*`, which is maybe what needs your `rename` function as second argument?

If you are trying to use standard [rename](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rename/) function, this may solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, I searched google for a long time, I just didn't what I should be searching, exactly. This solved my problem.