# Cannot convert a numerical string from a string array into a float

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

I am trying to convert an array that contains string into a float. Every string at index [j][2] will be a number which must be converted into a float. i is an int that contains the total number of "rows" of the array. First, I need to multiply it by 8 and then divide by 10, then convert it into a string and store it back into the array. I want to convert it into a float again at a later time but I need a record of which index each float belongs to. So I need a reliable method of converting string into floats. The following fails and gives me this error message:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    float wow = strtof(array[j][2]);
    array[j][3] = (wow + float(i/10)*8);
}
```

Error:

> cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘float strtof(const char*, char**)’

Variations of `strtof` like `stof` and `atof` give me the same error.

Comment: The simple answer here is to use `array[j][2].c_str()`, and there are many variations of questions asking about similar function calls.

Comment: Given the error message, also a "true" duplicate of [How to convert a std::string to const char* or char*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

Answer (score 4):

You are using the wrong function.  To convert a `std::string` to a `float` you need to use [`std::stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) not `strtof`.

Note: `std::stof` requires C++11 or higher.  If you do not have that you can use `atof` but you need to use `c_str()`.

Comment: I do not have C++11. However, when I use `float wow = strtof(array[j][2].c_str())`, It says there are too few arguments.

Comment: @Reginsmal I had a mistake in my answer.  You should use `atof` if you do not have C++11.  `float wow = atof(array[j][2].c_str())`