# C++ std::move unexpected behaviour (moving string when intended for smart pointer)

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

When I pass a string literal to a dynamically allocated unique_ptr and then store in vector (using std::move since there's apparently no other way), I get an odd return value when the string is fetched - it appears to have been cut/moved.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Something {
private:
    const char* name;
public:
    Something(const char* name) {
        this->name = name;
    }

    void printDetails() {
        std::cout << this->name << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Something>> stuff;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::unique_ptr<Something> thing(new Something("A nice fun string" + i));
        stuff.push_back(std::move(thing));
    }

    for(uint i = 0; i < stuff.size(); i++) {
        stuff[i]->printDetails();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A nice fun string
 nice fun string
nice fun string
ice fun string
ce fun string
e fun string
 fun string
fun string
un string
n string
```

Comment: And what's wrong with output?

Comment: You're storing a pointer to the address of the start of a string constant + i.

Comment: It has absolutely nothing to do with unique pointers. You should try to create an MCVE and see for yourself.

Comment: I see that you have learned some Java before. There are many things you need to unlearn.

Comment: @molbdnilo meh java is my main language. This was merely made as a test to move away from raw pointers then i ran into this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not moved. `"ABC"` is string literal, and actually is just a pointer `char const *`. Adding integer just moves it forward, so `"ABC" + 1` acts like `"BC"`.

C-style string literals are just char arrays, and arrays, when you access their contents, are just pointers to their first element. So adding integer th this pointer will work as suffix of your array.

What you want is probably concat your literal and integer, it's not so easy in C++. The fastest approach using C++11 looks terrible:

```
string("ABC") + to_string(i)
```

And, if you really want `char *` in the end, **copy** the resulting string of that (it's well described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char))

```
(string("ABC") + to_string(i)).c_str()
```

Comment: I wouldn't store the result of `c_str()` from a temporary.

Comment: "arrays are just pointers to their first element" - that's completely incorrect.

Comment: @T.C. when you do aceess an array it's working like pointer to the first element. There are limitations: string literals are unchangable and you can't reassign that pointer.

Comment: @LapshinDmitry arrays decay into pointers, but they are not pointers.

Comment: @Simple okay, I have not written the idea well, will edit.

Comment: @Bo Persson: I wouldn't even store it from a non-temporary ;)

Answer (score 3):

This part causes the error:

```
("A nice fun string" + i)
```

i must be a char or a char* itself, you are increasing the index of "A nice fun string" by i.