# Errors using atoi ("argument of type 'int*' is incompatible with type 'const char*' ") and adding arrays

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm attempting to create a program which extracts a polynomial equation from a file and adds, subtracts, or multiplies the two polynomials together (depending upon the middle operand).  However, I'm getting a two compiler errors that I can't quite make sense of.

The first occurs here:

```
int** getPolynomial(string polynomial, int &count, string Exponent[], string Coefficient[], int polyArray[][1]){
for (int i = 0; i<100; i++){
    for (int n = 0; n<100; n++){


Exponent[n] = atoi(polyArray[n][1]);
        }
        Coefficient[i] = atoi(polyArray[i][0]);

}
```

}

Where I'm getting an error "argument of type 'int*' is incompatible with type 'const char*' " on the lines
 `Exponent[n] = atoi(polyArray[n][1]);
        }
        Coefficient[i] = atoi(polyArray[i][0]);`

Second error occurs just below,

```
int** add(int **left, int leftCount, int **right, int countRight, int &countResult){
for (int q; q < leftCount; q++){
    for (int r = 0; r < 2; r++){
        if (left[q][1] == right[q][r]){
            countResult[q][0] = left[q][0] + right[q][0];
        }
    }
}
```

}

On the line `countResult[q][0] = left[q][0] + right[q][0];`, where the compiler is noting that the first q "expression must have pointer-to-object type", although I can't see how making q a pointer would help.

Full code here: http://pastebin.com/FsM1ydE5.  Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, isn't it? `polyArray[i][0];` isn't a `const char*` type as required.

Comment: I'm trying to convert the strings in array 'Coefficient' to ints in the array 'polyArray' though.  Do I have the positions of the two arrays mixed up?

Comment: The assignment operator takes the value on its right and assigns it to the var on its left.  That's kinda basic stuff..

Comment: Sounds like you're fighting windmills :-P. Stop using raw arrays and pointers. Have a thorough look at [The c++ standard containers library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Comment: I think I can use the information [on this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char) to fix the problem with needing to use const char* when I've got strings. Any idea whats up with the q in countResult needing to be a pointer apparently?  I tried simply changing it to one in the for loop but as expected that really didn't help due to how the loop is built.

Answer (score 1):

You're having trouble with your types:

1. [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) returns an `int`, so you'll either need to change `Exponent` and `Coefficent` to `int[]` or you'll need to stop using `atoi` and just assign the value directly.
2. `CountResult` is an `int&` which means that it cannot be indexed. You'll need to make it an `int[][]` to use it as you are currently.

---

This post would be incomplete without some direction: Use [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)s to represent your polynomials. You can use the index to indicate the exponent and the value to indicate the coefficient, as long as your polynomials will be relatively dense.

Now let's say that we're given `string polyArray[][]` which contains our powers and their coefficients in position 0 and 1 of the secondary array, respectively. And we want to read this into `vector<int> foo` which will represent our polynomial. We could just do:

```
for(auto& i : polyArray)
    if(i[0] > size(foo)){
        foo.resize(i[0]);
    }
    foo[i[0]] = i[1];
}
```

Now let's say that we're given 2 polynomials that we want to sum, say `vector<int> left` and `vector<int> right`, and we want to sum these into a newly constructed polynomial: `vector<int>countResult`, we can do this as follows:

```
if(size(left) > size(right)) {
    countResult.reserve(size(left));
    transform(cbegin(right), cend(right), cbegin(left), begin(countResult), plus<int>());
    countResult.insert(end(countResult), next(cbegin(left), size(right)), cend(left));
} else {
    countResult.reserve(size(right));
    transform(cbegin(left), cend(left), cbegin(right), becing(countResult), plus<int>());
    countResult.insert(end(countResult), next(cbegin(right), size(left)), cend(right));
}
```