# How to convert const *char to std::string

Tags: c++, char, constants

Im getting these errors because i cant convert correctly const char* to std::string....

> In file included from ./../Header Files/MainGame.h:5:0,
>                    from ./MainGame.cpp:2,
>                    from main.cpp:1: ./../Header Files/../Source Files/Hangman.cpp: In member function ‘void
>   Hangman::checkIfItEquals(std::string)’: ./../Header Files/../Source
>   Files/Hangman.cpp:55:41: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to
>   ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
>            std::string charStr = string(*it)
>                                            ^ In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52:0,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
>                    from ./../Header Files/MainGame.h:2,
>                    from ./MainGame.cpp:2,
>                    from main.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:490:7: error:   initializing
>   argument 1 of ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits,
>   _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc =
>   std::allocator]’ [-fpermissive]
>          basic_string(const _CharT* __s, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc());
>          ^ In file included from ./../Header Files/MainGame.h:5:0,
>                    from ./MainGame.cpp:2,
>                    from main.cpp:1: ./../Header Files/../Source Files/Hangman.cpp:56:9: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘if’
>            if(guessLet.compare(charStr) == 0)
>            ^

And here is the code.... Im going to give it all if other code has any relation to the problem..

Hangman.cpp:

```
#include<vector>
#include "../Header Files/Hangman.h"

Hangman::Hangman()
{
}

void Hangman::run()
{
    this -> mainGame();
    this -> mainGameLoop();
}


void Hangman::mainGame()
{
    dictonary.init();
    randomString = dictonary.randomItem();
    cout << "RANDOM STRING : " << randomString << endl;
    stringToVec();
}

void Hangman::stringToVec()
{
    for(std::string::iterator it = randomString.begin(); it != randomString.end(); ++it) 
    {
        randStringVec.push_back(*it);
    }
}


void Hangman::mainGameLoop()
{
    try{
         cout << " \n Guess A Letter (MUST BE A LETTER OR EXIT) \n";
         std::cin >> userGuessLetter;
         if(userGuessLetter.length() > 1)
             throw "Too Big Of a letter";
    } 
    catch(const char* exc)
    {
       if(true)
       {
          exit(1);
       }
    }

    cout << "You typed " << userGuessLetter << endl;
}

void Hangman::checkIfItEquals(string guessLet)
{
    for(std::vector<char>::iterator it = randStringVec.begin(); it!=randStringVec.end(); it++)
    {
        std::string charStr = string(*it)
        if(guessLet.compare(charStr) == 0)
        {
            cout << "GOOD JOB.. THERE IS A SIMMILAR LETTER!" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}


Hangman::~Hangman()
{
}
```

Hangman.h:

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include "../Source Files/Drawer.cpp"
#include "../Source Files/Dictonary.cpp"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;


class Hangman
{
public:

    Hangman();
    ~Hangman();
    void run();
private:
    Drawer hgmnDraw;
    Dictonary dictonary;
    std::vector<char> randStringVec;
    string randomString;
    string userGuessLetter;
    void mainGame();
    void drawHangMan(int attempts, int mode);
    void checkIfItEquals(string guessLet);
    void stringToVec();
    void mainGameLoop();
    int attemptsMadeBad = 0, attemptsMadeGood = 0;
    bool correctGs;
};
```

**EDIT**

After BenjaminLindley Comment below on the question i made the edit.. and elivated one error but 2 of the same errors still presist:

> In file included from ./../Header Files/MainGame.h:5:0,
>                    from ./MainGame.cpp:2,
>                    from main.cpp:1: ./../Header Files/../Source Files/Hangman.cpp: In member function ‘void
>   Hangman::checkIfItEquals(std::string)’: ./../Header Files/../Source
>   Files/Hangman.cpp:55:41: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to
>   ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
>            std::string charStr = string(*it);
>                                            ^ In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52:0,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
>                    from ./../Header Files/MainGame.h:2,
>                    from ./MainGame.cpp:2,
>                    from main.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:490:7: error:   initializing
>   argument 1 of ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits,
>   _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc =
>   std::allocator]’ [-fpermissive]
>          basic_string(const _CharT* __s, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc());

### ANOTHER EDIT

Basically im not converting char const* correctly to string:

```
for(std::vector<char>::iterator it = randStringVec.begin(); it!=randStringVec.end(); it++)
    {
        std::string charStr = string(*it);
        if(guessLet.compare(charStr) == 0)
        {
            cout << "GOOD JOB.. THERE IS A SIMMILAR LETTER!" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
```

As you can see on second line i am typecasting but that is not working according to this error:

```
In file included from ./../Header Files/MainGame.h:5:0,
                 from ./MainGame.cpp:2,
                 from main.cpp:1:
./../Header Files/../Source Files/Hangman.cpp: In member function ‘void Hangman::checkIfItEquals(std::string)’:
./../Header Files/../Source Files/Hangman.cpp:55:41: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
         std::string charStr = string(*it);
                                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from ./../Header Files/MainGame.h:2,
                 from ./MainGame.cpp:2,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:490:7: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ [-fpermissive]
       basic_string(const _CharT* __s, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc());
```

Comment: Look at the last line of your error message.

Comment: Ok @BenjaminLindley that help elevate that problem.. But the first two problem still presist.. i will edit in a second to the problems that still presist

Comment: @JohnDoe It would help if you pointed out the line with the error.  No one is going to wade through and count lines to figure out where the error is.

Comment: Ok im going to put it in format.. basically i am not converting... Sec @PaulMcKenzie Let me edit to make it more precice

Comment: Ok I finished editing it @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Ok i edited it again @BenjaminLindley

Comment: You `#include` your .cpp files?

Comment: Yes there are 2 more files.. Errors are not even there so dont be concerened about those please.. @kfsone . Im coding this here: https://ide.c9.io/antihuman/fornoreason So thats where im working it at, if you want to see the cpp files go there..[Awesome Online IDE]

Comment: @JohnDoe What is your goal?  Is it to attempt to initialize a `std::string` with a single char?

Comment: Ok @PaulMcKenzie basically im trying to convert const char* to std::string

Comment: Basically the opposite of this @PaulMcKenzie : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char?rq=1

Comment: @JohnDoe - That is not what your code is doing.  Where is the `const char*` in this line: `std::string charStr = string(*it);`, and `it` is an iterator that when dereferenced, is a single `char`?  Did you inspect with the debugger what `*it` really is?  What you are winding up doing (and failing) is taking a single char and trying to make a string out of it.

Comment: yes its a const char* look at the error it states that @PaulMcKenzie at line 5 or 6

Comment: You're not trying to convert a `const char *` to a string, you're trying to convert a `char` to a string.

Comment: @JohnDoe Did *you* look at the error? "invalid conversion from `char` to `const char*`"

Comment: Ahhh @immibis my mind is very confused!! How do i convert this char or stuff, to string?

Comment: @JohnDoe You don't. You need to take a step back, and figure out what you actually want your program to do, instead of just changing things until it compiles.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie anwsered question!! Im just stupid sorry @immibis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your goal seems to be to convert a single `char` to a `std::string`.

You cannot initialize a `std::string` with a single `char`.  What will wind up happening is that the compiler will try and promote the `char` to a `const char *`, exactly as the error describes.

What you want is the `std::string` constructor that takes a single character and a count:

```
 std::string charStr = string(1, *it);
```

See the link [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) and look at constructor `2)`

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.. Im just stupid