# Modern C++ way to copy string into char*

Tags: c++, string, c++11

What is the modern way to do this? Headers like `<cstring>` are deprecated and "C-like" functions are banned by some coding styles. I have three approaches of doing the same thing. Which one would be most idiomatic of modern C++?

**1.** Use iterators and include the null terminator

```
{
    std::string test{"hello, world!"};
    char* output = new char[test.size() + 1];
    std::copy(test.begin(), test.end(),
        output);
    output[test.size() + 1] = '\0';
    std::cout << output;
    delete output;
}
```

**2.** Use `c_str()` which includes the null terminator

```
{
    std::string test{"hello, world!"};
    char* output = new char[test.size() + 1];
    std::copy(test.c_str(), test.c_str() + std::strlen(test.c_str()),
        output);
    std::cout << output;
    delete output;
}
```

**3.** Use `std::strcpy`

```
{
    std::string test{"hello, world!"};
    char* output = new char[test.size() + 1];
    std::strcpy(output, test.c_str());
    std::cout << output;
    delete output;
}
```

I don't want to look like a noob to an interviewer who say "Oh you use strcpy, you must be a C programmer".

Comment: If I were you, I'd worry about exception safety, wrap the whole block with a `try`, and catch `std::bad_alloc`. Also, "Headers like <cstring> are deprecated" - since when?!

Comment: What *exactly* is the target-datastructure? Is it malloc-allocated 0-terminated string? Or is it "accessible 0-terminated string"? Or actually really the bastardized new-allocated 0-terminated string?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Since C++98. Crazy, I know.

Comment: Nothing really bad about showing experience with C, as the only time you would be likely to do this is creating a compatibility layer with C. (C++ standards generally regard it as depreciated to convert std::string to a c-string. )

Comment: @Deduplicator Legacy interface that takes `char**`

Comment: No, `<cstring>` is definitely *not* deprecated. `<string.h>` is, but `<cstring>` is a normal standard header.

Comment: @user6364501 : [citation needed]

Comment: And what exactly does that interface specify?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a std::string to const char\* or char\*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

Comment: Should be using `delete [] output;` in all the above as well.

Answer (score 18):

The <strike>modern</strike> safe pre C++17 way to obtain a contiguous buffer is `std::vector`.

```
std::string test{"hello, world!"};
std::vector<char> output(test.c_str(), test.c_str()+test.size()+1);
// use output.data() here...
```

Since C++17, `std::string` has a non-const `data()` overload.

```
std::string test{"hello, world!"};
char * p = test.data();
```

Answer (score 10):

The right way is not using `new[]` in the first place. Use `std::vector` instead:

```
std::string temp {"Some string"};
std::vector<char> data (begin(temp), end(temp));
// If '\0' termination is required:
data.push_back('\0');
```

You can access they underlying buffer of `data` with `data.data()`. If you are concerned about a reallocation due to the `push_back`, you can `std::vector::reserve` enough space before assigning the range.

If you don't need an actually modifiable `char` array, you can skip the copy and just use the pointer returned by `std::string::data` or `std::string::c_str` directly.

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers offer good advice, and are the correct way to do things in almost all circumstances, there are some genuine cases where you might be forced to use a `char*` instead of a container. The most common case will be if you need to interface directly with C code, and the called C-method requires a non-`const` pointer (i.e. it will take ownership of the memory).

This is how I would make the conversion:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

char* convert(const std::string& source)
{
    const auto result = (char*) std::malloc(source.length() + 1);
    source.copy(result, source.length());
    result[source.length()] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

Then you have something like:

```
int main()
{
    const std::string foo {"hello"};
    auto p = convert(foo);
    some_nasty_c_method(p); // promises to free p
    // other stuff
}
```

As a rule of thumb, if you need to `delete` yourself, don't do this; use a container, or `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::vector<char> v(foo.begin(), foo.end()); some_nasty_c_method(v.data());`?

Comment: @ChristianHackl `std::vector::data` returns a `const` pointer.

Comment: @Daniel: [One overload does but there also is a non-const overload.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) It is true however, that a function that is to call `free` on a given pointer is required to get a pointer obtained via `malloc`. This is hopefully specified in the interface description and then there is no question which method should be used / is best, because you're bound to use `malloc` anyway.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: The problem with `std::vector<char> v(foo.begin(), foo.end());` is the missing null character which is usually expected by legacy string-handling C code (if there is no size parameter in which case one could skip the '\0').