# Write a char dynamically including a variable int Arduino

Tags: arrays, arduino

How to write a char[] with unknown length including a variable integer ( length of integer is variable) like this:

```
char data[] = "{""LDRValue"":" + LDRReading + "}";
```

LDRReading is the only variable.

here is the code:

```
int LDRReading = analogRead(LDR);
int d = LDRReading;
int b = d - c;
if (b > 50 || b < -50) {
  c = d;
//    String data = "{""LDRValue"": ";
//    data = data + LDRReading;
//    data = data + "}";
  char data[] = "{\"LDRValue\": 300}";
  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to LDR server...");
  if (client.connect(server, 8060)) {
    Serial.println("connected to LDR post server");
    client.println("POST /api/sensor HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: 192.168.2.123");
    client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(strlen(data));
    client.println();
    client.print("{\"LDRValue\":");
    client.print(LDRReading);
    client.print("}");
    delay(300);
   }
  Serial.println(d);
  client.stop();
```

Comment: Use `std::ostringstream` to format strings.

Comment: is this question related to `arduino` or `c++`? They are **not** the same thing.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I thought I was wrong to mention C++ in my question, because some answers seems to be right but when I compile it give me "Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino MKR1000" so can you help me with this problem?

Comment: @bilal1409 Is there any particular reason why you don't use the [String Object](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) provided by the Arduino Library rather than a *character array*? It is designed exactly for the use case you are presenting here: handling strings of variable length.

Comment: As I said in other comment, when I use String data = ..... it does not work with http post request. I works only when I use char data[] = .........

Comment: @bilal1409 Could you please add the code related your http post request to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EthernetClient`, which is the object-class you are using, is sub-class of `Client` which is sub-class of `Stream` which is sub-class of `Print`, so it *should* work printing a *String* object through the **client** instance, as `Print` has the following methods:

```
size_t print(const String &);
size_t print(const char[]);
size_t println(const String &s);
size_t println(const char[]);
```

---

Therefore, this should work:

```
int LDRReading = analogRead(LDR);
int d = LDRReading;
int b = d - c;
if (b > 50 || b < -50) {
  c = d;

  String data = "{\"LDRValue\": ";   // FIXED: escaped " symbols
  data = data + LDRReading;
  data = data + "}";

  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to LDR server...");
  if (client.connect(server, 8060)) {
    Serial.println("connected to LDR post server");
    client.println("POST /api/sensor HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: 192.168.2.123");
    client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(data.length());
    client.println();

    client.print(data); // FIXME: why don't you use println() here?
    client.flush();     // NOTE: this is strongly advised to push all
                        //      data in a stream out if you don't add
                        //      a line feed.

    delay(300);
  }
  Serial.println(d);
  client.stop();
}
```

Notice the comment that I added in the code: I think you should either use a `println()` or invoke `client.flush()` afterwards to ensure that the data you are printing on the stream is effectively pushed out. I wrote `client.print()` only to not alter your original code.

---

If, for some specific reason, you believe that there is a specific issue with printing data as a **String**, then you can always obtain its **char[]** equivalent by invoking `data.c_str();` on it:

```
    client.print(data.c_str());
    client.flush();
```

Comment: Thank you it works but I use "client.println(data.length() );" instead of "client.println(strlen(data));"

Comment: @bilal1409 right, I didn't check the other lines, fixed it :)

Comment: One last thing. DO you know something about Web socket on Arduino?

Comment: @bilal1409 I don't use them in my projects, as I don't have a shield with network capability. So I know only what I can read from the source code of the Arduino library. ;)

Comment: I use Websocket between Raspberry Pi and server and it works perfect, as the theory of websocket. But when I search for a websocket for Arduino I found a lot of libraries and may be all of them is just like http post not like the real websocket.

Answer (score -2):

Why not just use std::string?

```
std::string s("{""LDRValue"":" + LDRReading + "}");
const char* szData = s.c_str();
```

If you cannot use std::string for whatever reason you could determine the length of your content first by using for example **strlen** and then creating a char array by calling **new**

Comment: Why store an std string as a char*? Why not keep it as a string?

Comment: Of course it's better to keep it as string, i added the way of getting a char* from std::string because he was asking for a char array :)

Comment: The temporary `string` is destroyed at the end of the line, so subsequent use of `szData` causes undefined behaviour

Comment: Plain wrong. Pointer to temporary which goes out of scope at the `;`.

Comment: I want it char [] because http post does not work with string, it works with char

Comment: @bilal1409 you know a string is made of chars, right

Comment: It's worth noting that char* and char[] are syntactically interchangable in C.

Comment: @bilal1409 you can get C string from a [`std::string str` by `str.c_str()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/347949/995714)

Comment: @M.M when I used (   string data = "{""LDRValue"":" + LDRReading + "}";   )  it does not work

Comment: @bilal1409 Sure it doesn't work. Use `std::ostringstream` as I mentioned.

Comment: @bilal1409 that line is wrong, but still,  a string is made of chars