# 'MessageBoxA' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'LPCSTR'

Tags: c++, type-conversion, stdvector, lpcstr

The following code works:

```
void CMyPlugin8::myMessageBox(std::string& myString)
{
    myString = "Received the following string\n" + myString;
    char * writable = new char[myString.size() + 1];
    std::copy(myString.begin(), myString.end(), writable);
    writable[myString.size()] = '\0'; // don't forget the terminating 0 "delete[] writable;"

    int msgboxID = MessageBox(
        NULL,
        writable,
        "Notice",
        MB_OK
    );
    delete[] writable;
}
```

To clean up automatically I used info from : [How to convert a std::string to const char* or char*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char).

The following code throws an error:

```
void CMyPlugin8::myMessageBox(std::string& myString)
{
    myString = "Received the following string\n" + myString;
    std::vector<char> writable(myString.begin(), myString.end());
    writable.push_back('\0');

    int msgboxID = MessageBox(
        NULL,
        writable,
        "Notice",
        MB_OK
    );
}
```

I'm getting this error:
***'MessageBoxA' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'LPCSTR'***

Comment: Why are you copying into a `vector`? (or for that matter copying at all?) `c_str` works just fine for this case.

Comment: You meant likely meant `writable.data()`.

Comment: Thanks @François that works. Not sure what you mean about using c_str and how I would implement that. I tried writable.c_str() and that gives a different error 'c_str' : is not a member of 'std::vector<_Ty>'

Comment: @Michael Others are suggesting that you use `std::string`'s `c_str()` directly, rather than copying it into a `vector` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MessageBox` takes a `const char*`. You don't need to copy the string first for that. Simply use `c_str`:

```
void CMyPlugin8::myMessageBox(std::string& myString)
{
    myString = "Received the following string\n" + myString;
    int msgboxID = MessageBox(
        NULL,
        myString.c_str(),
        "Notice",
        MB_OK
    );
}
```

Note that I think your API is poor: you are modifying the value of the string passed in. Usually the caller wouldn't be expecting that. I think your function should look like this instead:

```
void CMyPlugin8::myMessageBox(const std::string& myString)
{
    std::string message = "Received the following string\n" + myString;
    int msgboxID = MessageBox(
        NULL,
        message.c_str(),
        "Notice",
        MB_OK
    );
}
```

Comment: Tried the last option you posted above I get an error: | 'void CMyPlugin8::myMessageBox(const std::string &)' : overloaded member function not found in 'CMyPlugin8'|

Comment: You didn't fix the header file. The parameter is now `const` to ensure that it cannot be modified unintentionally.

Comment: Jackpot thanks!  I thought i missed something there. That works

Answer (score 4):

You cannot pass a vector as LPCSTR, you must. Use:

```
&writable[0]
```

or:

```
writable.data()
```

instead. Or simply use `myString.c_str()`

Answer (score 0):

```
void CMyPlugin8::myMessageBox(const std::string& myString)
{
    std::string message = "Received the following string\n" + myString;
    int msgboxID = MessageBox(
        NULL,
        message.c_str(),
        "Notice",
        MB_OK
    );
}
```

Thanks everyone & @Falcon

Comment: Actually modifying passed in variable is not good idea, I would recoment changing it to `const std::string& myString`, and inside function do `std::string tmp = "received ........`. You dont need vector here. Also if you ever will change to UNICODE build then you will find that all your char should be now wchar_t.

Answer (score 0):

If you still face a problem, after changing it myString.c_str().
Try this,
Go to the **Properties** for your Project and under **Configuration Properties/Advanced**, change the Character Set to **"Not Set"**. This way, the compiler will not assume that you want Unicode characters, which are selected by default:

[image]