# Why does hash<const char*> work for strings but not string variables?

Tags: c++, hash

My question is why does the following code work

```
hash<const char*> PassHash;

cout << PassHash("Hello World");
```

But this code wont compile.

```
hash<const char*> PassHash;
string password;
password = "Hello World";

cout << PassHash(password);
```

In Code Blocks I get this error

```
error: no match for call to '(__gnu_cxx::hash<const char*>) (std::string&)'|
```

Comment: Because a `std::string` is not a `const char*`, and there are no applicable conversion operators. Use `password.c_str()`. [Related conversion question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char).

Comment: Because a `string` isn't a `const char *`... Why does `cout << PassHash(42);` not work?

Comment: ps if you are planning to use this for an actual password - note that std::hash doesn't necessarily produce the same output for the same input the next time the program is run.

Comment: "_note that std::hash doesn't necessarily produce the same output for the same input the next time the program is run_" ... is this actually true? I would appreciate a link to some reference.

Comment: @Martin "note that std::hash doesn't necessarily produce the same output for the same input the next time the program is run" ... is this actually true? I would appreciate a link to some reference.

Comment: @zett42 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash or your copy of the c++14 std

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed the C++14 note. Citing: "_Hash functions are only required to produce the same result for the same input within a single execution of a program; this allows salted hashes that prevent collision DoS attacks._"

Comment: @MartinBeckett Is there a hashing function of some kind I can use for a password? Hopefully one that produces the same output even on multiple executions

Comment: @tenben Use a secure hashing function that is designed for the purpose sha-1 (or if security is a real concern one of the more secure replacements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion from `std::string` to `const char*` which would be required to make your example work.

You may call `string::c_str()` to explicitly do this "conversion"...

```
hash<const char*> PassHash;
string password;
password = "Hello World";

cout << PassHash(password.c_str());
```

... but this will only calculate the **hash of the string pointer** because there is no specialization for `hash<const char*>`! So this only matches the generic pointer specialization `hash<T*>`.

What you propably really want is **hash over the entire character array** of the string, so if one character of the string changes, you (most likely) get a different hash value.

For this you could use the `hash<std::string>` specialization. This works for both `const char*`and `std::string` arguments as expected, because std::string has a conversion constructor that takes a `const char*`.

Example:

```
const char* password1 = "Hello World";
string password2 = "Hello World";

hash<const char*> charPtrHasher;

// This only calculates a hash from the value of the pointer, not from 
// the actual string data! This is why you get a different hash for each.
cout << "Test 1:\n";
cout << charPtrHasher(password1) << endl << charPtrHasher(password2.c_str()) << endl;

hash<std::string> stringHasher;

// This correctly calculates the hash over all characters of the string!
cout << "\nTest 2:\n";
cout << stringHasher(password1) << endl << stringHasher(password2) << endl;
```

Live Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/047c099f5dcff948

Comment: To the editor of my post... what's wrong about `std::string::data()`? I think it adds consistency (e. g. compare to `std::vector::data()`).

Comment: You propably refer to the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data): "_The returned array is not required to be null-terminated._" ... but for `hash<const char*>` it doesn't make a difference because it just hashes the pointer anyway (there is no specialization for C strings).

Answer (score 4):

`std::hash` has a definition similar to the following

```
template<typename T>
struct hash {
  size_t operator()(const T& value) const {
    ...
  }
}
```

So it's trivial that `std::hash<const char*>` template instantiation defines an `operator()` which accepts a `const char*`, but you are passing a `std::string` which is a different type.

Just use directly `std::string` for your password variable and `std::hash<std::string>` instead.

Comment: You can use `const char*` as argument for `std::hash<std::string>` too because it will implicitly be converted to std::string. The more important difference between `std::hash<const char*>` and `std::hash<std::string>` is that the former only hashes the pointer whereas the latter hashes the entire string.

Comment: @zett42: which is a substantial difference, using `std::hash<const char*>` can lead to weird obscure behavior if you don't know what you are doing. For example two `const char*` representing the same sequence but allocated on heap at different locations.