# How to create a char array from string constant?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I try to create a `char* values[]` for my unittests that will be written but initialized from constants. The naive way throws a warning that ISO C++ forbids it:

```
char* single[1];
single[0] = "foobar";
```

I tried the following that obviously does not work:

```
std::string executable = "foobar";
std::array<char, executable.size()> data; // Error: size not known at compile time
std::copy(executable.begin(), executable.end(); data.data());

char* single[1];
single[0] = data.data();
```

There must be a way like:

```
std::array<char> data = { "foobar" };
char* single[1];
single[0] = data.data();
```

Comment: In C++ string literals are constant character arrays. So you have to write for example const char* single[1];
single[0] = "foobar";

Comment: @VladfromMoscow But I need `char**` so I can freely manipulate the data. The constness is in the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::string foo = "foobar";
std::vector<char> data(foo.data(), foo.data()+foo.size()+1u);
char* single[1];
single[0] = data.data();
```

[How to convert a std::string to const char* or char*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char/34748132#34748132)

You can use some kind of transformation function if this pattern reoccurs:

```
template<class CharT, std::size_t N>
std::vector<CharT> literal_vector(CharT const (&a)[N])
{
    return std::vector<CharT>(&a[0], (&a[0]) + N);
}
```

and then

```
std::vector<char> lv = literal_vector("Hello");
single[0] = lv.data();
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to add [`to_array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/to_array) to your toolbox. Then you can simply write

```
auto data = to_array("foobar");
char* single[1];
single[0] = data.data();
```

Comment: This is a great find, too bad it's not standard yet.

Answer (score 3):

Even though your question has not been tagged as c++1z, it is worth mentioning that the constness restriction of the `data` function of `std::string` has been lifted in the current working draft of the Standard ([N4618](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4618.pdf)), which is about to be published as C++17. In [basic.string], one can find both:

> ```
> const charT* data() const noexcept;
> charT* data() noexcept;
> ```

Your compiler may already have support for it, possibly needing the compiler flag `-std=c++1z` or similar. If so, you should be able to write:

```
std::string executable = "foobar";
char *single[1];
single[0] = executable.data();
```

Comment: This is the minimal approach I want and hopefully will use soon.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have tow ways, both of them are using memcpy.

1. Using dynamic memory.
2. Using static memory.

```
 

    using namespace std;

    #define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 250
    int main()
    {
        const char* myData = "This is My Data";

        int sizeOfmydata = std::strlen(myData);;

        //1.- Dinamic Memory
        char* data1 = new char[sizeOfmydata];
        std::memcpy(data1, myData, sizeOfmydata);

        //2.- Static Memory
        char data2[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
        memset(data2, '\0', MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
        std::memcpy(data2, myData, sizeOfmydata);


        delete[] data1;
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit long but it seems to do what you need. This is file `foo.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> strings = {"foobar", "barbaz"};

    char* values[strings.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); ++i) {
        values[i] = new char[strings[i].size() + 1];
        std::copy(strings[i].cbegin(), strings[i].cend(), values[i]);
        values[strings[i].size()] = '\0';
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", values[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Then:

```
$ make foo
g++     foo.cpp   -o foo
$ ./foo
foobar
barbaz
```

You should of course `delete` each of the elements of the array of `char*`, and maybe put the loop for copying from `std::string` to `char*` in a function and so on.

PS: auch, this solution is identical to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/347959/7473772) that someone already linked.... The linked other answer has more detail. Does that mean your question is a duplicate? I let experienced users decide.

Comment: No I want `char* val[]` or `char** val` because I need to manipulate the array and it's values.

Comment: @aggsol sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: @aggsol Now I think I did better :) at least it is easy to write all literals and then you just copy them to memory you create with `new` which is I am afraid unavoidable if you don't want `const`ness

Answer (score -1):

You can use `std::vector<std::string>` to store your data, and use `c_str()` of `std::string` to parse your string to `char*`

Comment: `c_str()` returns `const char*` not `char *`

Comment: You can change it back like @pergy did

Comment: Which is probably unsafe and UB.

Comment: @Pixelchemist What does UB mean?

Comment: @aggsol: [Undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) which essentially means: The c++ standard doesn't provide a guarantee about it. Using `const_cast` on the return value of `c_str` and manipulating the data through the resulting pointer **might** work... today... if you jump twice ... and if the sun is brighter than yesterday... on your compiler ...