# c++ no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "const char*" exists

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, implicit-conversion, c-strings

the question as the title suggests, is an error when i was executing my program in the certain part of the password function. actually it is a basic password function which was working properly in turbo c++, but in visual c++
this error arrives

```
void user::password()
 {
  char any_key, ch;
  string pass;
  system("CLS");        
  cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t*****************\n\t\t\t\t*ENTER 
            PASSWORD:*\n\t\t\t\t*****************\n\t\t\t\t";
  start:
  getline(cin,pass);
   if (strcmp(pass, "sha") == 0)           //this is where the error is!*
    {
       cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\t ACCESS GRANTED!!";
       cout << "\n\t\t\t PRESS ANY KEY TO REDIRECT TO HOME PAGE";
       cin >> any_key;
    }
   else
    {
       cout << "\n\t\t\t\t ACCESS DENIED :(,RETRY AGAIN!!\n\t\t\t\t";
       goto start;
    }
  system("CLS");
  }
```

Comment: Side issue, see [why goto is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3517726/10957435).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression in the if statement

```
if (strcmp(pass, "sha") == 0)
```

is incorrect.

The function requires the both parameters of the type const char * while you supplied the first argument of the type std::string and there is no implicit conversion from the type std::string to the type const char *.

Use instead

```
if ( pass == "sha" )
```

In this case there is an implicit conversion from the type const char * (the type of the string literal after its implicit conversion from the array type) to an object of the type std::string due to the non-explicit constructor

```
basic_string(const charT* s, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

Comment: Actually, a `string` doesn't get constructed, there's an `operator==` overload for `const char*` so it's as efficient as `strcmp(pass.data(), "sha");` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/

Answer (score 3):

You can also convert the **string** to a **const char*** and perform the comparison with strcmp.

```
if (strcmp(pass.c_str(), "sha") == 0)
```

Comment: If this is your solution, then it is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char).