# hot to convert std::__cxx11::string to std::string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, casting, stdstring

so i just want to convert int in digits and store it in array

for eg

```
int n=456;

std::string nstr = std::to_string(n);

std::cout << nstr[0];
```

now i just want the length of `nstr`...

whenever i am using `std::strlen(nstr)`;

its giving an error

```
**error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'const char*'**
```

please tell me how to convert `std::__cxx11::string` to `std::string`

or is there any other way to calculate length of `nstr`

Comment: Why use `strlen()` instead of `std::string::size()`?

Comment: `strlen` is for character arrays, you can just use `nstr..size()`

Comment: `std::string` has a `size` and `length` member functions that do this for you.  `strlen` is for c-strings, not `std::string`s

Comment: You can convert a `std::string` to `const char*` with `c_str()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char).

Comment: Not only is using `strlen()` not correct, A call to `strlen()` is an `O(n)` operation, where `n` is the number of characters (including) the terminating null.  A call to `size()` is an `O(1)` operation, since a `std::string` knows the number of characters stored without having to look for a null.  So even if you got your code to work with `strlen`, it is slower than using `size`.

Comment: `std::__cxx11::string` _is_ `std::string`. Your error is clearly about converting to `const char*`, not about converting to `std::string`, so I don't understand why you ask about the latter in the question title and body...

Answer (score 2):

> hot to convert std::__cxx11::string to std::string

`std::__cxx11::string` **is** (a name of) `std::string` in the standard library implementation that you use.

`std::string` cannot be passed to `std::strlen`, because it requires the argument to be `const char*` instead, as explained in the error message.

> or is there any other way to calculate length of nstr

Typically, you should use the `size` member function. No calculation is involved however. The size was calculated when the string was created, and then stored within the string object.

Answer (score 1):

If you really, really, really want to use `strlen()`, you have to convert to `char*`:

```
std::strlen(nstr.c_str());
```

But usually you would just ask the string for its size:

```
nstr.size();
```

The only reason I can think of you might prefer `strlen()` is if you have embedded nulls in your string, and you want to stop your count there.