# length of char array using dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, dynamic

Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
char* getString(char*& s)
{
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    int length = str.length();
    s = (char*)malloc(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        s[i] = str[i];
    return s;
}

void main()
{
    char* s;
    getString(s);
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

In my `getString()` function, I create a string `str` and pass the input string to it. Then I calculate for the length of `str` and then allocate this number of bytes for the char array `s`. But the problem is, when i call for `strlen(s)`, the return value is not equal to the length of string `str`, so when i print out `s` to the console, it's not the string i want. Anyone can tell me why and explain more about it??

Comment: This is C++ code, not C code, and should be tagged with the C++ tag, not the C tag.

Comment: No it's not @d4rk4ng31

Comment: Oh okay, its a reference!! Sorry

Comment: This is just for practice, yes? In ordinary code there will not ordinarily be a reason to do this - just pass the actually `std::string` around.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a std::string to const char\* or char\*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes, my instructor asked me to use the dynamic allocation the solve the task.

Comment: this is c++ use `new` instead of malloc()

Comment: If you have to do things a specific way because of an assignment specification, you should explain this up front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an array of characters the very last byte is called the *null terminator*, which is `\0` in this case. Its what tells your program where the end of the characters in an array are.

The `str.length()` function returns how many bytes are in a string. A null character does not count as a byte. So when `str.length()` goes to count how many characters are in your array, it counts until it reaches `\0`.

When you need to create a new array of the same 'size' as the string, you must make it one byte longer in order to accommodate the null terminator.

So your code should be:

```
s = (char*)malloc(length + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate one more character than [`str.length()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) to allow for the null character that terminates the string, and you need to set that character to the null character.

Comment: Also, if this answer worked for you, please accept it