# Illegal indirection when trying to make an std::;string to a void*

Tags: c++, pointers, void

I have a library that I'm using where a function takes a void *, but the text I'm trying to pass is of type std::string. So I did

```
void CastToVoid(std::string *data)
{
    void *temp = *(static_cast<void*>(data));
}
```

And am using it like

```
            foregroundWindow = GetActiveWindowTitle();
            CastToVoid( static_cast<std::string*>(&foregroundWindow));
            Speak(&foregroundWindow); // Where speak is what takes the void*
```

This yields illegal indirection. Any idea why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a std::string to const char\* or char\*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

Comment: `CastToVoid` doesn't do anything and pointers are automatically converted to `void*`. So `CastToVoid` can be safely removed. Take a look at documentation for `Speak` and see what argument it actually expects. Maybe you simply _can't_ pass a string there.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Speak(void *)` function takes an untyped/void pointer, it's unclear what sort of argument it is expecting.  i.e. is `Speak()` expecting its argument to be a pointer to a NUL-terminated byte array, or is it expecting its argument to be a pointer to a `std::string` object?  Since `void *` is untyped, either one will compile, but passing in the "wrong" argument will likely cause a crash or other undefined behavior at runtime.

That said, if `Speak(void *)` is implemented to expect its argument to point to a `std::string`, then you could call it like this (as you do above):

```
Speak(&foregroundWindow);
```

or if `Speak(void *)` is implemented to expect its argument to be a pointer to a NUL-terminated char array, you could instead call it like this:

```
Speak(const_cast<void *>(foregroundWindow.c_str()));
```

The best approach, though would be to modify the argument-type of the `Speak()` method to specify the type of the pointer it takes, rather than accepting a `void *`, so that the compiler could flag an error when the programmer passes in an inappropriate value, rather than allowing the programming error to pass undetected and cause a runtime malfunction.  So something like:

```
void Speak(std::string * pointerToStdString);
```

or better yet (if Speak() doesn't need to modify the `std::string`):

```
void Speak(const std::string * pointerToStdString);
```

or (if Speak() just needs the pointer-to-the-NUL-terminated-chars-array)

```
void Speak(const char * pointerToChars);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here is the code.
```
void Speak(void *text)
{
 if (!eciAddText(eciHandle, text))
 {
  printf( "eciAddText failed\n" );
 }
 if (!eciSynthesize(eciHandle))
 {
  printf( "eciSynthesize failed\n" );
 }
 if (!eciSynchronize(eciHandle))
 {
  printf( "eciSynchronize failed\n" );
 }
}
```
What approach would you suggest based off that?

Comment: Oh and here's the line causing a problem.  void *temp = *(static_cast<void*>(data));

Comment: Yes, that line is a problem, because the asterisk just after the `=` is trying to dereference a `void *`, which isn't a sensible thing to do.  (i.e. if you dereference an `int *` that give you an `int`, which makes sense, but trying to dereference a `void *` would give you... a `void`?  What is a `void`?  A `void` is by definition an unknown type, so the operation isn't allowed)

Comment: ... and in any case, as @churill mentioned in his comment above, the entire `CastToVoid` function doesn't do anything useful, since even if it compiled and ran, all it is doing is declaring a local variable and then getting rid of that local variable when the function returns, so it has no effect on anything the program does.

Comment: @Turret Where did you get that code from? `eciAddText` takes a `const char*`, and removing that type information is counterproductive. (Try `Speak(foregroundWindow.c_str())`.

Comment: Omg... it worked... I feel stupid... thank you. And to answer your question, it's from eci.h, for interfacing to the IBM Eloquence synthesizer.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` is a container object, which holds information about a string. Under the hood, it looks something like this (just for the sake of explaining),

```cpp
class string {
public:
    string() {}
    
    ...
    // Other member functions.

private:
    char* pData = nullptr;
};
```

As you can see, the `std::string` itself isnt a string type (meaning `std::string` is not `" "`). So casting it to `void*` will result in undefined behavior.

If your goal is to pass the string data as `void*`, then use [`std::string::c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) to get the actual string data as `const char*`. This way you can pass the string to the function you want.