# How to convert string to const char[] in c++

Tags: string, visual-c++, vex

I am working on a C++ project for a Vex Robot, I am using a function that takes a `const char[]` but for showing an integer, there is no such function that converts to `const char[]`, so is there a way to do that. All the search results showed how to convert to `const char*` and by the way "string" is of type `const char[]`.

EDIT:
I also need to covert the string to concatenate tow strings (but ended up just coverting both strings to std::string and then back to const char[])

Comment: A function that takes `const char[]` will accept `const char*`.

Comment: There is the [`std::string::c_str()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a std::string to const char\* or char\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

Comment: also I found * string.c_str() also works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `std::string` there is the function [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) (with the synonym [`data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) since C++11) to get a pointer to the underlying null-terminated character array:

```
std::string const myString{"stackoverflow"};
const char* cstr = myString.c_str();
const char* data = myString.data();
```