# no suitable conversion function from "const std::string" to "char *" exists?

Tags: c++, vector

im trying to make a simple program that list all txt file in the directory then append **hello world** in them but i face an issue while passing the vector into WriteFiles Function

this is the following code i've tried to fix it for a while any oil be grateful for any help

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <fstream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    void ListFiles(vector<string>& f) // list all files
    {
        FILE* pipe = NULL;
        string pCmd = "dir /b /s *.txt ";
        char buf[256];
    
        if (NULL == (pipe = _popen(pCmd.c_str(), "rt")))
        {
            return;
        }
    
        while (!feof(pipe))
        {
            if (fgets(buf, 256, pipe) != NULL)
            {
                f.push_back(string(buf));
            }
    
        }
    
        _pclose(pipe);
    
    
    }
    
    void WriteFiles (const char* file_name)
    {
        std::ofstream file;
    
        file.open(file_name, std::ios_base::app); // append instead of overwrite
        file << "Hello world";
        file.close();
    
    }
    
    int main()
    {
    
        vector<string> files;
        ListFiles(files);
        vector<string>::const_iterator it = files.begin();
        while (it != files.end())
        {
            WriteFiles(*it); // the issue is here
            cout << "txt found :" << *it << endl; 
            it++;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a std::string to const char\* or char\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

Comment: Too much Yoda. `FILE* pipe = _popen(pCmd.c_str(), "rt"); if (!pipe) return;`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default constructing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `std::ofstream file; file.open(file_name, std::ios_base::app);` to `std::ofstream file(file_name, std::ios_base::app);`. Also, you don't have to call `file.close()`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: C++ has a filesystem library. I'd recommend using that instead of piggybacking on `dir`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WriteFiles(it->c_str());` will fix the problem. Iterators act a lot like pointers, so that's how you access a method indirectly.

Comment: @Atrox I am sorry, I can't debug it for you right now. Use your debugger to see what's up. Good luck